# How can I parse a YAML file in Python

Tags: python, yaml

How can I parse a YAML file in Python?

Answer (score 1424, accepted):

The easiest and purest method without relying on C headers is PyYaml ([documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)), which can be installed via **`pip install pyyaml`**:

```
import yaml

with open("example.yaml") as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

And that's it. A plain `yaml.load()` function also exists, but `yaml.safe_load()` should always be preferred to avoid introducing the possibility for arbitrary code execution. So unless you explicitly need the arbitrary object serialization/deserialization use `safe_load`.

Note the PyYaml project supports versions up through the [YAML 1.1 specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/spec.html). If [YAML 1.2 specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) support is needed, see [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/) as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922434/313192).

Also, you could also use a drop in replacement for pyyaml, that keeps your yaml file ordered *the same way you had it*, called [oyaml](https://github.com/wimglenn/oyaml). View [synk of oyaml here](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/oyaml)

Comment: I would add that unless you wish to serialize/deserialize arbitrary objects, it is better to use ``yaml.safe_load`` as it cannot execute arbitrary code from the YAML file.

Comment: Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Object obj = yaml.load("a: 1\nb: 2\nc:\n  - aaa\n  - bbb");

Comment: I like the article by moose: http://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/

Comment: You may need to install the PyYAML package first `pip install pyyaml`, see this post for more options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python

Comment: What's the point of capturing the exception in this example? It's going to print anyway, and it just makes the example more convoluted..

Comment: Also, plain `yaml.load` has become deprecated and it should be used with Loader argument, eg. `yaml.load(input, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)`. `yaml.safe_load(input)` is still ok. https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation

Comment: I feel like this should really be a 1 liner. Why isn't there just a `yaml.read()` api or the like that returns a dict?

Comment: See [Munch](https://pypi.org/project/munch/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570869/load-yaml-as-nested-objects-instead-of-dictionary-in-python
`import yaml; from munch import munchify; f = munchify(yaml.load(…));
print(fo.d.try)`

Comment: stay away from pyyaml. There is no documentation, and nobody seems to be maintaining it; there are over a hundred unresolved issues.

Comment: `YAML 1.1 specification` link is dead == https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/

Comment: @ternaryOperator What do you mean by `serialize/deserialize arbitrary objects`? Is it not safe to use `yaml.safe_load` if I am not using arbitrary objects?

Comment: A drop in replacement for pyyaml, that keeps your yaml file ordered *the same way you had it*, is [oyaml](https://github.com/wimglenn/oyaml). View [synk of oyaml here](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/oyaml)

Comment: This answer doesnt protect you from `billion laught yml` attack.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Zuku, if performance is important to you, consider YAML C bindings: `yaml.load(input,taml.SafeLoader` or `yaml.load(input, yaml.CFullLoader`. The `safe_load` convenience function calls the pure Python variant only.

Answer (score 229):

### Read & Write YAML files with Python 2+3 (and unicode)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import yaml
import io

# Define data
data = {
    'a list': [
        1, 
        42, 
        3.141, 
        1337, 
        'help', 
        u'€'
    ],
    'a string': 'bla',
    'another dict': {
        'foo': 'bar',
        'key': 'value',
        'the answer': 42
    }
}

# Write YAML file
with io.open('data.yaml', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)

# Read YAML file
with open("data.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)

print(data == data_loaded)
```

### Created YAML file

```
a list:
- 1
- 42
- 3.141
- 1337
- help
- €
a string: bla
another dict:
  foo: bar
  key: value
  the answer: 42
```

### Common file endings

`.yml` and `.yaml`

### Alternatives

- CSV: Super simple format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585079/562769))
- JSON: Nice for writing human-readable data; VERY commonly used ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769))
- YAML: YAML is a superset of JSON, but easier to read ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054860/562769), [comparison of JSON and YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729545/562769))
- pickle: A Python serialization format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769)) ⚠️ Using pickle with files from 3rd parties poses an uncontrollable arbitrary code execution risk.
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) ([Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python)): More compact representation ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43442194/562769))
- [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) ([Python package](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)): Nice for matrices ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586571/562769))
- XML: exists too *sigh* ([read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/562769) & [write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/562769))

For your application, the following might be important:

- Support by other programming languages
- Reading / writing performance
- Compactness (file size)

See also: [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)

In case you are rather looking for a way to make configuration files, you might want to read my short article [Configuration files in Python](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/)

Comment: What encoding does the file have? Your you sure it is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. My file has utf-8 encoding. I had to change your code line to `io.open(doc_name, 'r', encoding='utf8')` to read the special character. YAML version 0.1.7

Comment: Huh, interesting. I will try to reproduce that tomorrow and will adjust the question if I can. Thank you!

Comment: You can use the built-in `open(doc_name, ..., encodung='utf8')` for read and write, without importing `io`.

Comment: You use `import yaml`, but that isn't a built-in module, and you don't specify which package it is.  Running `import yaml` on a fresh Python3 install results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'`

Comment: I think this is referring to package pyyaml which gets imported as yaml

Comment: Personally I'd add a big disclaimer to pickle if you list it, namely that it poses a significant arbitrary code execution risk and shouldn't be used with untrusted data. [The official Python docs for pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) say as much in a big red box: "Warning The pickle module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust.".

Comment: @bob I've added the warning.

Comment: `pip install pyyaml` for `import yaml` to work

Answer (score 86):

If you have YAML that conforms to the [YAML 1.2 specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) (released 2009) then you should use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).
It is essentially a superset of PyYAML, which supports most of YAML 1.1 (from 2005).

If you want to be able to preserve your comments when round-tripping, you certainly should use ruamel.yaml.

Upgrading @Jon's example is easy:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

with open("example.yaml") as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Use `safe_load()` unless you really have full control over the input, need it (seldom the case) and know what you are doing.

If you are using pathlib `Path` for manipulating files, you are better of using the new API ruamel.yaml provides:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('example.yaml')
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(path)
```

Comment: Hello @Anthon. I was usiing ruamel's but got an issue with documents that are not ascii compliant (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 926: ordinal not in range(128)`). I've tried to set yaml.encoding to utf-8 but didn't work as the load method in YAML still uses the ascii_decode. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 61):

First install pyyaml using pip3.

Then import yaml module and load the file into a dictionary called 'my_dict':

```
import yaml
with open('filename.yaml') as f:
    my_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

That's all you need. Now the entire yaml file is in 'my_dict' dictionary.

Comment: If your file contains the line "- hello world" it is inappropriate to call the variable my_dict, as it is going to contain a list. If that file contains specific tags (starting with ``!!python``) it can also be unsafe (as in complete harddisc wiped clean) to use `yaml.load()`. As that is clearly documented you should have repeated that warning here (in almost all cases `yaml.safe_load()` can be used).

Comment: You use `import yaml`, but that isn't a built-in module, and you don't specify which package it is. Running `import yaml` on a fresh Python3 install results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'`

Comment: See [Munch](https://pypi.org/project/munch/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570869/load-yaml-as-nested-objects-instead-of-dictionary-in-python
`import yaml; from munch import munchify; f = munchify(yaml.load(…));
print(fo.d.try)`

Answer (score 16):

To access any element of a list in a YAML file like this:

```
global:
  registry:
    url: dtr-:5000/
    repoPath:
  dbConnectionString: jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:abcd
```

You can use following python script:

```
import yaml

with open("/some/path/to/yaml.file", 'r') as f:
    valuesYaml = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(valuesYaml['global']['dbConnectionString'])
```

Answer (score 12):

**Example:**

---

> **defaults.yaml**

```
url: https://www.google.com
```

> **environment.py**

```
from ruamel import yaml

data = yaml.safe_load(open('defaults.yaml'))
data['url']
```

Comment: is it save to not close the stream?

Comment: I thought it is, but is it? related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512990/does-python-gc-close-files-too

Comment: @qrtLs It is definitely not safe. You should explicitly close the descriptor every time and this have some reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25070939/3338479

Answer (score 2):

I use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml). <s>Details & debate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805418/pyyaml-dump-format)</s>.

```
from ruamel import yaml

with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    read_data = yaml.load(fp)
```

Usage of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) is compatible (with some simple solvable problems) with old usages of PyYAML and as it is stated in link I provided, use

```
from ruamel import yaml
```

instead of

```
import yaml
```

and it will fix most of your problems.

**EDIT**: PyYAML is not dead as it turns out, it's just maintained in a different place.

Comment: @Oleksander: PyYaml has commits in the last 7 months, and the most recent closed issue was  12 days ago. Can you please define "long dead?"

Comment: @abalter I apologize, seems that I got the info from their official site or the post right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760452/5510526

Comment: @OleksandrZelentsov I can see the confusion. There was a loooong period when it was dead. https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/graphs/contributors. However, their site IS up and shows releases posted AFTER the SO post referring to PyYaml's demise. So it is fair to say that at this point it is still alive, although it's direction relative to ruamel is clearly uncertain. ALSO, there was a lengthy discussion here with recent posts. I added a comment, and now mine is the only one. I guess I don't understand how closed issues work. https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/145

Comment: @abalter FWIW, when that answer was posted, there had been a total of 9 commits in the past... just under 7 years. One of those was an automated "fix" of bad grammar. Two involved releasing a barely-changed new version. The rest were relatively tiny tweaks, mostly made _five_ years before the answer. All but the automated fix were done by one person. I wouldn't judge that answer harshly for calling PyYAML "long dead".

Answer (score 1):

I made my own script for this. Feel free to use it, as long as you keep the attribution. The script can parse yaml from a file (function `load`), parse yaml from a string (function `loads`) and convert a dictionary into yaml (function `dumps`). It respects all variable types.

```py
# © didlly AGPL-3.0 License - github.com/didlly

def is_float(string: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def is_integer(string: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def load(path: str) -> dict:
    with open(path, "r") as yaml:
        levels = []
        data = {}
        indentation_str = ""

        for line in yaml.readlines():
            if line.replace(line.lstrip(), "") != "" and indentation_str == "":
                indentation_str = line.replace(line.lstrip(), "").rstrip("\n")
            if line.strip() == "":
                continue
            elif line.rstrip()[-1] == ":":
                key = line.strip()[:-1]
                quoteless = (
                    is_float(key)
                    or is_integer(key)
                    or key == "True"
                    or key == "False"
                    or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
                )

                if len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2 < len(levels):
                    if quoteless:
                        levels[len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2] = f"[{key}]"
                    else:
                        levels[len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2] = f"['{key}']"
                else:
                    if quoteless:
                        levels.append(f"[{line.strip()[:-1]}]")
                    else:
                        levels.append(f"['{line.strip()[:-1]}']")
                if quoteless:
                    exec(
                        f"data{''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}]"
                        + " = {}"
                    )
                else:
                    exec(
                        f"data{''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}']"
                        + " = {}"
                    )

                continue

            key = line.split(":")[0].strip()
            value = ":".join(line.split(":")[1:]).strip()

            if (
                is_float(value)
                or is_integer(value)
                or value == "True"
                or value == "False"
                or ("[" in value and "]" in value)
            ):
                if (
                    is_float(key)
                    or is_integer(key)
                    or key == "True"
                    or key == "False"
                    or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
                ):
                    exec(
                        f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}] = {value}"
                    )
                else:
                    exec(
                        f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}'] = {value}"
                    )
            else:
                if (
                    is_float(key)
                    or is_integer(key)
                    or key == "True"
                    or key == "False"
                    or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
                ):
                    exec(
                        f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}] = '{value}'"
                    )
                else:
                    exec(
                        f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}'] = '{value}'"
                    )
    return data


def loads(yaml: str) -> dict:
    levels = []
    data = {}
    indentation_str = ""

    for line in yaml.split("\n"):
        if line.replace(line.lstrip(), "") != "" and indentation_str == "":
            indentation_str = line.replace(line.lstrip(), "")
        if line.strip() == "":
            continue
        elif line.rstrip()[-1] == ":":
            key = line.strip()[:-1]
            quoteless = (
                is_float(key)
                or is_integer(key)
                or key == "True"
                or key == "False"
                or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
            )

            if len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2 < len(levels):
                if quoteless:
                    levels[len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2] = f"[{key}]"
                else:
                    levels[len(line.replace(line.strip(), "")) // 2] = f"['{key}']"
            else:
                if quoteless:
                    levels.append(f"[{line.strip()[:-1]}]")
                else:
                    levels.append(f"['{line.strip()[:-1]}']")
            if quoteless:
                exec(
                    f"data{''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}]"
                    + " = {}"
                )
            else:
                exec(
                    f"data{''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}']"
                    + " = {}"
                )

            continue

        key = line.split(":")[0].strip()
        value = ":".join(line.split(":")[1:]).strip()

        if (
            is_float(value)
            or is_integer(value)
            or value == "True"
            or value == "False"
            or ("[" in value and "]" in value)
        ):
            if (
                is_float(key)
                or is_integer(key)
                or key == "True"
                or key == "False"
                or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
            ):
                exec(
                    f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}] = {value}"
                )
            else:
                exec(
                    f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}'] = {value}"
                )
        else:
            if (
                is_float(key)
                or is_integer(key)
                or key == "True"
                or key == "False"
                or ("[" in key and "]" in key)
            ):
                exec(
                    f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}[{key}] = '{value}'"
                )
            else:
                exec(
                    f"data{'' if line == line.strip() else ''.join(str(i) for i in levels[:line.replace(line.lstrip(), '').count(indentation_str) if indentation_str != '' else 0])}['{key}'] = '{value}'"
                )

    return data


def dumps(yaml: dict, indent="") -> str:
    """A procedure which converts the dictionary passed to the procedure into it's yaml equivalent.

    Args:
        yaml (dict): The dictionary to be converted.

    Returns:
        data (str): The dictionary in yaml form.
    """

    data = ""

    for key in yaml.keys():
        if type(yaml[key]) == dict:
            data += f"\n{indent}{key}:\n"
            data += dumps(yaml[key], f"{indent}  ")
        else:
            data += f"{indent}{key}: {yaml[key]}\n"

    return data


print(load("config.yml"))
```

### Example

#### `config.yml`

```yaml
level 0 value: 0

level 1:
  level 1 value: 1
  level 2:
    level 2 value: 2

level 1 2:
  level 1 2 value: 1 2
  level 2 2:
    level 2 2 value: 2 2
```

#### Output

```json
{'level 0 value': 0, 'level 1': {'level 1 value': 1, 'level 2': {'level 2 value': 2}}, 'level 1 2': {'level 1 2 value': '1 2', 'level 2 2': {'level 2 2 value': 2 2}}}
```

Comment: it so cool! But i does not working with lists like

`one:\n
  - two\n
  - three
`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the `pyyaml` library, together with the in-built `pathlib` library.

You will need to build a `pathlib.Path` object first:

```
from pathlib import Path
import yaml

path: Path = Path("/tmp/file.yaml")
# Make sure the path exists
assert path.exists()
# Read file and parse with pyyaml
dictionnaire = yaml.safe_load(path.read_text())
```

This works fine with modern versions of Python 3.

You do not need with use the `open` file method this way. The code is a slightly more concise and you can easily check if the file exists, before you actually try to parse the YAML file.

Answer (score -2):

read_yaml_file function returning all data into a dictionary.

```py
def read_yaml_file(full_path=None, relative_path=None):
    if relative_path is not None:
        resource_file_location_local = ProjectPaths.get_project_root_path() + relative_path
    else:
        resource_file_location_local = full_path

    with open(resource_file_location_local, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            file_artifacts = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
    return dict(file_artifacts.items())
```