# CSV features to KML file and Styling Python

Tags: python, google-earth, simplekml

I have a csv file with business_name, coordinates, business_type, and price_range columns.

How do I convert to KML file while at the same time keep the info such as business_type and price_range in the text box when the business is selected? Right now only business_type is appearing in the box shown in yellow below. I'd like both info to be in.

[image]

How do I make the styling different depending on the business type and price range? I'm using Python and SimpleKML library

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Does this answer [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881715/20851944)