# Creating an XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a simple XML file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python)

I want to write a XML file from Python.
The XML is like the following format only:

```
<Title rollid="1" mainid="1" teamid="1">
<s name="hello" address"abcdef" "etc"/>
 <s name="" address="" />
</Title>
```

I wrote code in Python using `lxml` and `etree` but the XML file which I get is like this:

```
<Title>
<s>rollid=""1" mainid="1"</s>
<s>name="" address=""</s>
<s>name="" address=""</s>
</Title>
```

Please let me know how to get the desired format

My Code:

```py
import os
import sys
```

import lxml.builder as lb
    from lxml import etree

```
#i made a dummy file AddDetail.xml with the root tags

def WriteDetails(rolid,mainid,name,address):
    myhash=dict()   # Declaring a dictionary

    #Storing the data which has to be written to xml in a dictionary
    myhash={'rollid':rolid, 'mainid':mainid,  'name':name, 'opid':opid, 'address':address}

    # Converting the data from dictionary to string for XML and 
    also checking if any valueis 0
    data=' '.join([('%s="%s"')%(key,value) for key,value in myhash.iteritems()if value])

    # Creating the root Element
    root=etree.Element("Title")

    # Making a new Document Tree
    doc=etree.parse('AddDetail.xml')

    # Getting the root tag
    root=doc.getroot()

    # Adding a new Element
     y=lab.E.Title(lb.E.s(data),
    rollid="1" mainid="1" teamid="1")
    print etree.tostring(y,pretty_print=true)

   output i get is

   <Title rollid="1" mainid="1" teamid="1">
   <s>name="hello" address="aaaa"</s>
   </Title>

   I need something like
   <Title rollid="1" mainid="1" teamid="1">
   <s name="hello" address="aaaa"/>
   </Title>
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python?rq=1

Comment: this looks like a typo: address"abcdef"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lxml.builder, [here's](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory) a tutorial too.

```
   import lxml.builder as lb
   from lxml import etree

y=lb.E.Title(lb.E.s(name="hello",adress="abcdef"),
             lb.E.s(name="",adress=""),
             rollid="1", mainid="1",teamid="1")

print etree.tostring(y, pretty_print=True)

>>> 
<Title teamid="1" rollid="1" mainid="1">
  <s adress="abcdef" name="hello"/>
  <s adress="" name=""/>
</Title>
```

Comment: if instead of printing the value of name and address, if i pass a variable then the format gets changed. i get something like     <s>dasff</s>

Comment: editied my old question only..

Comment: no, you should not edit your old question, if you have a new one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145773/can-i-replace-an-old-question-by-editing-it your original question has been correctly answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to create attributes:

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes

```
>>> root = etree.Element("root", interesting="totally")
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root interesting="totally"/>'
```