# Is there a way to include greater than or less than signs in an XML file?

Tags: xml

I have an XML file from a client that has greater than `>` and less than `<` signs in it and it fails an XML format check.
Is there a way to get around this without asking the client to fix the file?

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<note Name="PrintPgmInfo <> VDD">
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: If you don't want to ask the client to fix the file, then the obvious solution is for you to fix it yourself.  If it's a one-off thing, edit it and replace the reserved characters with the predefined entity references; if this will happen repeatedly, write a sed script or the equivalent in your batch editor of choice to make the change.  (If you don't have a batch editor of choice and you face problems like this, you should learn about batch editors and get good at one.)

Answer (score 43):

You may try to use it like this:

```
< = &lt;

> = &gt;
```

These are known as [Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 25):

You will have to use XML escape characters:

```
" to  &quot;
' to  &apos;
< to  &lt;
> to  &gt;
& to  &amp;
```

Google escaping characters in XML for more information.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question plainly **no**, you cannot have an XML file with `<` or `>` in any of its value fields because the XML format uses these characters to signify the parent and child elements, e.g. `<note>`, `<to>`, `<from>`, etc.

Expanding on my answer: When a Python script writes `<` or `>` using the [XML library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), the library translates them to `&lt` or `&gt`, respectively. I don't believe this is possible with that library since it is actually filtering out the `<` and `>` characters as well as the Character Entity References. This makes sense - the XML library is preventing you from disrupting the syntax used for the parent `xml.etree.cElementTree.Element` or any child `xml.etree.cElementTree.SubElement` object fields. For example, use the code block in this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/404469) to experiment:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

ET.SubElement(doc, "field1", name="blah").text = "some <value>"
ET.SubElement(doc, "field2", name="asdfasd").text = "some <other value>"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

This yields `<root><doc><field1 name="blah">some &lt;value&gt;</field1><field2 name="asdfasd">some &lt;other value&gt;</field2></doc></root>`.

Prettifying it:

```
<root>
    <doc>
        <field1 name="blah">
            some &lt;value&gt;
        </field1>
        <field2 name="asdfasd">
            some &lt;other value&gt;
        </field2>
    </doc>
</root>
```

---

However, there's nothing stopping you from adding these characters manually: read in the XML file and re-write it, adding text, even if it contains `<` or `>`. If you want a proper XML file though, just be sure that these characters are only used within comment fields.

**For your particular problem,** you could read in the lines from the client's XML files, then either remove the `<` and `>` characters or, if the client requires them, move them to a commented portion of the line. Part of the challenge is that you have to leave in the `<note>,``, etc. portions of the file... This is challenging but it would be possible!

The following is what I'd expect the result to look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<note Name="PrintPgmInfo VDD"> <!-- PrintPgmInfo <> VDD -->
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question:

> Is there a way to get around this without asking the client to fix the file ?

is "no".  The data you are getting is not valid XML, and you are correct in rejecting it.  I highly recommend going back to the client and saying that they must provide valid XML, using Character Entity References as mentioned by David and Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the similarly looking full-width less-than (U+FF1C) and full-width greater-than (0xFF1E) signs: ＜＞

These Unicode characters do not require special encoding.