# How to put < in XML as a string in android studio?

Tags: xml, string

How can I put the char `<` in XML?
Whenever I try to put it, it shows some kind of error. I know how to put double quotes and quotes, but for me this is getting difficult.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to include greater than or less than signs in an XML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398950/is-there-a-way-to-include-greater-than-or-less-than-signs-in-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting an XML-entity like `<` in an XML file is accomplished by using the appropriate `escape-value`.
This [WikiPedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) explains that the correct encoding for the `<` char is `&lt;`.

Comment: Thanks but i have one more quest i.e. how to make the code area in application similar to the code area in android studio website. I mean we see the background of codes on these websites are different than the normal text background. How to highlight the syntax and keyword on android application page.

Comment: I'm sorry. but this is a whole new question. So you should open it as another question. I don't know much about _Android Studio_, so opening a new question for another audience will seriously improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.