# xmlformatter ignore less than in quotes

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-formatting

I am trying to format the following xml

```
<block formula="MY_VAR < 3"><set-variable name="OTHER_VAR"></set-variable></block>
```

into

```
<block formula="MY_VAR < 3">
  <set-variable name="OTHER_VAR">
  </set-variable>
</block>
```

using [xmlformatter](https://pypi.org/project/xmlformatter/) and getting an error because of the `<` in my formula. Specifically the error is

> ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)

when I try the code

```
my_xml = '<block formula="MY_VAR < 3"><set-variable name="OTHER_VAR"></set-variable></block>'
formatter = xmlformatter.Formatter(indent="1", indent_char="  ", encoding_output="UTF-8", preserve=["literal"])
pretty_xml = formatter.format_string(my_xml)
```

How do I include the less than in my formula and be able to format my XML?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398950/is-there-a-way-to-include-greater-than-or-less-than-signs-in-an-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr) to escape the attribute value when constructing the xml string.

```
>>> my_xml = '<block formula=%s><set-variable name="OTHER_VAR"></set-variable></block>' % su.quoteattr('MY_VAR < 3')
>>> my_xml
'<block formula="MY_VAR &lt; 3"><set-variable name="OTHER_VAR"></set-variable></block>'
```

If you don't control construction of the xml this hack will fix the xml in the  example:

```
stack = []

out = []
brackets = '<>'

for c in bad_xml:
    if c in brackets:
        try:
            prev = stack[-1]
        except IndexError:
            stack.append(c)
            out.append(c)
        else:
            if prev == c:
                escaped = '&gt;' if c == '>' else '&lt;'
                out.append(escaped)
            else:
                stack.append(c)
                out.append(c)
    else:
        out.append(c)
my_xml = ''.join(out)
```