# How ignore element in XML file with JAXB converter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have XML file provide with contact inside , and some time  look like->

```
<ResponsableContact>test test(test.test@test.com<test.test@test.com>)</ResponsableContact>
```

but when  i try to convert my XMLFile with JAXB it generate error

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>
> - with linked exception:
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1128; columnNumber: 88; Le type d'élément [email].... doit être suivi des spécifications d'attribut, ">" ou "/>".]

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListeXML")
public class ListeXML{
    
    private String dateDeGeneration;
...
    private List<Dom> listeDom;
    
    public ListeXML() {
        super();
    };
}
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dom {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    ...
    @XmlTransient
    private String responsableContact;

}
```

How ignore this element type is not real xml type ?

I can't change the XML file  beacause it generate by the one else

Comment: Share the class and  the xml file please

Comment: Basically the xml is invalid. You need valid xml to be converted to objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398950/is-there-a-way-to-include-greater-than-or-less-than-signs-in-an-xml-file

Comment: I changed the formart of the xml example because obviously stackoverflow has a problem with <>

Comment: @(Nice Books) I can't edit the xml file, do you have another method than jaxb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAXB - Ignore element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044042/jaxb-ignore-element)

Comment: i add this annotation @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) and @XmlTransient same error

Comment: Your XML is invalid, because within XML elements, a `<` must be encoded as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`.

Comment: the solution to change with &lt; and &gt; is not thinkable