# Python writing to an xml file

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to write to an xml file.  I have changed a specific element in my code, and am able to get it to print successfully.  I need to have it written to the file, without changing the structure of the file.
My code:

```
import os
from lxml import etree


directory = '/Users/eeamesX/work/data/expert/EFTlogs/20160725/IT'
XMLParser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    if f.endswith(".xml"):

        xmlfile = directory + '/' + f



        tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
        root = tree.getroot()

        hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")



        if hardwareRevisionNode.text == "5":
            print " "
            print "Old Tag: " + hardwareRevisionNode.text

            x = hardwareRevisionNode.text = "DVT2"

            print "New Tag " +  hardwareRevisionNode.text
```

When I try various methods of opening and closing the file, it just deletes all the data in the xml file.  Using this method

```
outfile = open(xmlfile, 'w')
oufile.write(etree.tostring(tree))
outfile.close()
```

Changed the code structure of my file to be one long line.

Comment: There are pretty printers or indenters in lxml.  One long string is perfectly valid xml.  See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to replace a value within an existing XML file then use:

```
tree.write(xmlfile)
```

Currently you are simply overwriting your file entirely and using the incorrect method (`open()`). `tree.write()` is normally what you would want to use. It might look something like this:

```
tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
root = tree.getroot()
hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")
if hardwareRevisionNode.text == "5":
    print "Old Tag: " + hardwareRevisionNode.text
    hardwareRevisionNode.text = "DVT2"
    print "New Tag: " +  hardwareRevisionNode.text
    tree.write(xmlfile)
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: I needed to put it at the bottom and it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

To get newlines in the output file, it looks like you need to pass [`pretty_print=True`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) to your sterilization (`write` or `tostring`) call.

Side note; Normally, when you open files with python you open them like this:

```
with open('filename.ext', 'mode') as myfile:
    myfile.write(mydata)
```

This way there is less risk of file descriptor leaks. The [`tree.write("filename.xml")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/1342445) method looks like a nice and easy way to avoid dealing with the file entirely.

Comment: tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        tree.write(xmlfile)
        hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")

Comment: Changing to that results in the file being made into one line, and the text not being replaced

Comment: In the above snippet you are re-saving the original tree. See my edited answer for the newline problem.

Comment: It corrected the one line, but it doesnt write to the actual file.  It still says 5, instead of DVT3

Comment: tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        tree.write(xmlfile, pretty_print=True)
        hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")