# How to store data in XML file format Using Django

Tags: python, xml, django

I need to store my html form data in XML file save that file inside same project using Django. I am providing my code below:

insert.html:

```
<form method="post" action=" " onSubmit="return validateForm();" name="frmfeed">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input name="name" value="{{person.name}}">
    <br>
    <label>Phone: </label>
    <input name="phone" value="{{person.phone}}">
    <br>
    <label>Age: </label>
    <input type="number" name="age" value="{{person.age}}">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{person.id}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

view.py:

```
def insert(request): 
    # If this is a post request we insert the person
```

Here I need when user will submit the form the data will store in a xml file and format is given below.

```
<user>
  <name="Ram">
    <user id='12345'>
     <phone>9937229867</phone>
     <age>32</age>
   </user>
  </name>
</user>
```

I need to store in the above format.

Comment: Are you asking how to process the form data or how to parse the xml, or both? For just parsing the xml you can use the standard library, following question has a couple of good examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python

Comment: I need to save data into xml file instead of database.

Comment: You could save it as a `TextField`

Comment: @satya may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python