# Why is xml.etree.ElementTree considered insecure?

Tags: python, xml, security, elementtree

According to *[Creating a simple XML file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3605680/3357935)*, one of the simplest ways to generate an XML file in Python is to use Python's built-in ElementTree XML API.

However, [the Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) includes the following warning:

> **Warning:** The [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module is not secure against maliciously constructed data. If you need to parse untrusted or unauthenticated data see [XML vulnerabilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities).

I had planned on using the ElementTree library to construct XML requests with user-inputted attribute values. However, I am now concerned about the security of my application.

For example, my application has a `logon()` function with arguments for a user-inputted username and password. These values are then used as XML attributes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def logon(username, password):
    # Create XML logon request for external webservice
    root = ET.Element("xml")
    body = ET.SubElement(root, "Logon")
    body.set("Username", username)
    body.set("Password", password)

    return ET.tostring(root, encoding="UTF-8", method="xml")
```

**Why is `xml.etree.ElementTree` considered insecure? Is it safe to use with user-defined XML attribute values?**

Comment: Pretty sure that's about DoS when parsing. Since you're not parsing XML, you should be fine.

Comment: Did you read the "XML vulnerabilities" link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the section [20.4.1. XML vulnerabilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities) of the Python documentation, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) is vulnerable to the **Billion Laughs attack** and to the **quadratic blowup attack**.

> **billion laughs / exponential entity expansion**
>
> The Billion Laughs attack – also known as exponential entity expansion – uses multiple levels of nested entities. Each entity refers to another entity several times, and the final entity definition contains a small string. The exponential expansion results in several gigabytes of text and consumes lots of memory and CPU time.
>
> **quadratic blowup entity expansion**
>
> A quadratic blowup attack is similar to a Billion Laughs attack; it abuses entity expansion, too. Instead of nested entities it repeats one large entity with a couple of thousand chars over and over again. The attack isn’t as efficient as the exponential case but it avoids triggering parser countermeasures that forbid deeply-nested entities.

As long as you don't parse maliciously crafted XML, you are safe.