# To Generate the xml using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to generate the below xml using python

How do i generate? can some one please advise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="12" preserve-order="true" >
    <test name="MY">
        <classes>
            <class name="PIB_MY.Login" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.FundTransfer" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.BillPayment" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.AddManageDeletePayee" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.SmartClick" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.Logout" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Please check this Stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python

Comment: how do i get the doc type and xml version tags. Thanks

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks

Comment: Fine, no one knows what the question really was and no one will know "the solution" either, how usefull for a technical knowledge base #facepalm... Thanks for wasting everyone's time, really.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply:

```
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="12" preserve-order="true" >
    <test name="MY">
        <classes>
            <class name="PIB_MY.Login" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.FundTransfer" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.BillPayment" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.AddManageDeletePayee" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.SmartClick" />
            <class name="PIB_MY.Logout" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> 
"""

print(xml)
```

Voilà, problem solved.

Comment: I need to generate from the elements. Thanks

Comment: @garlapak sorry but that's nowhere in your question, so my answer is technically perfect. If you expect any useful answer (instead of downvotes, close votes and obviously ironic answers like this one), then  post a real question.