# How to create an XML file where all the tags are having null values using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an XML file using python (v3.6) where all the tags will be having no values. For example -

```
    <rootTag>
      <A></A>
      <B>
        <B1></B1>
        <B2></B2>
        <B3></B3>
      </B>
    </rootTag>
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You could try writing some code? Use e.g. ElementTree? Have you tried reading the documentation for ElementTree which includes some examples of creating XML.

Comment: You could check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python) for a start to writing XML files in Python.

Comment: Hi, actually I'm working in pySpark and my output file is XML. I'm using ElementTree in my current code to convert my spark generated dataframe to XML file. But somehow unable to create empty tag xml file with structured format as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create the required o/p xml file. As I'm working in pyspark and one part of my code demands to create the above xml file hence i thought of if there is any better approach using python. 
Anyhow, I've created dataframe with empty values and then store it as an XML file.

```
DF = spark.createDataFrame(' ',StringType()).alias('A')

DF = DF.withColumn('B',
        struct(
            lit(' ').alias("B1"),
            lit(' ').alias("B2"),
            lit(' ').alias("B3")
        ))
# ---- save the DF 
DF.repartition(1).select('*').\
    write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rootTag='rootTag').save(outputFileLocation)
```