# How to create in sitemap.xml?

Tags: python, sitemap.xml, custom-error-pages

I am not able create a sitemap with the following code?

```
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage('')
print(tree)

for page in tree.all_pages():
    print(page)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sitemap layout looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

</urlset>
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python) thread you can read how to create a xml file:

```py
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import simplejson as json

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage('https://www.nytimes.com/')

root = ET.Element("urlset", xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

for page in tree.all_pages():
    url = page.url
    prio = json.dumps(page.priority, use_decimal=True)
    # format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD see: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
    lm = page.last_modified.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z")
    cf = page.change_frequency.value
    urlel = ET.SubElement(root, "url")
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "loc").text = url
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "lastmod").text = lm
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "changefreq").text = cf
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "priority").text = prio

ET.indent(root, "  ") # pretty print
xmltree = ET.ElementTree(root)
xmltree.write("sitemap.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True )
```

If you want the `lastmod` to be todays date. Import date from datetime.

```
from datetime import date
```

and replace

```
page.last_modified.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z")
```

with

```
date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z")
```

sitemap.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-07-19T15:24+0000</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/about</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-07-19T15:24+0000</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

</urlset>
```

If you use https://www.example.com/ as your url you will not get the ouput above. Because example.com does not have a sitemap.xml. So use a different url.

Comment: @May that's because it takes the Date which is inside the websites sitemap

Comment: @May means I solved your problem!?