# How can I write data in YAML format in a file?

Tags: python, formatting, yaml, pyyaml

I need to write the below data to yaml file using Python:

```py
{"A": "a", "B": {"C": "c", "D": "d", "E": "e"}}
```

i.e., dictionary in a dictionary. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See also: [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1773805/562769)

Answer (score 288, accepted):

```
import yaml

data = dict(
    A = 'a',
    B = dict(
        C = 'c',
        D = 'd',
        E = 'e',
    )
)

with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

The `default_flow_style=False` parameter is necessary to produce the format you want (flow style), otherwise for nested collections it produces block style:

```
A: a
B: {C: c, D: d, E: e}
```

Comment: default_flow_style=True does the opposite as stated in the answer below!

Comment: Is there a benefit of using `with` here as opposed to the one-liner?

Comment: @src `with` ensures the file is closed properly when it is no longer needed

Comment: See [Munch](https://pypi.org/project/munch/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570869/load-yaml-as-nested-objects-instead-of-dictionary-in-python
`import yaml; from munch import munchify; f = munchify(yaml.safe_load(…));print(f.B.C)`

Answer (score 102):

[Link](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#FrequentlyAskedQuestions) to the PyYAML documentation showing the difference for the `default_flow_style` parameter. 
To write it to a file in block mode (often more readable):

```
d = {'A':'a', 'B':{'C':'c', 'D':'d', 'E':'e'}}
with open('result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

produces:

```
A: a
B:
  C: c
  D: d
  E: e
```

Comment: See [Munch](https://pypi.org/project/munch/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570869/load-yaml-as-nested-objects-instead-of-dictionary-in-python
`import yaml; from munch import munchify; f = munchify(yaml.safe_load(…));print(f.B.C)`

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, I had to use `sort_keys=False` to maintain the specific order in the dictionary, i.e.:

```
import yaml

data = {
    "mode" : 'separate-outputs',
    "parent" : 'd93fca33ec026010b521b3587beb5897dff43189a8e1b4da078846c40d680dcei0',
    "postage" : 690,
    "inscriptions" : [
        {"file": "mango.avif", "metadata": {"title": "test"}},
        {"file": "mango2.avif", "metadata": {"title": "test"}},
    ]
}

with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

#### data.yml

```
mode: separate-outputs
parent: d93fca55ec026010b521b3587beb5897dff43189a8e1b4da078846c40d680dcei0
postage: 690
inscriptions:
- file: mango.avif
  metadata:
    title: test
- file: mango2.avif
  metadata:
    title: test
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time this question was asked in 2012, the default flow style was None but [since PyYaml 5.1](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/commit/507a464ce62c933bf667b2296a96ad45f0147873), it's been False, so for recent versions of PyYaml (e.g. PyYaml 6.0.1), the nested objects are written in block style by default, i.e. the following code:

```py
import yaml
d = {'A': 'a', 'B': {'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e'}}

with open('data.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(d, f)
```

would produce a file that looks like

```yaml
A: a
B:
  C: c
  D: d
  E: e
```

Also, if you don't pass a file handle, `dump()` returns the data as a string, which can be written into a file as well.

```py
s = yaml.dump(d)

with open("data.yaml", "w") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

which again would produce the same file as above.

---

`default_flow_style=None` lets you mix styles:

```py
print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=None))
                   
A: a
B: {C: c, D: d, E: e}
```

while `default_flow_style=True` is straight up flow style:

```py
print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=True))
                   
{A: a, B: {C: c, D: d, E: e}}
```

Also, if you want to see valid kwargs of `dump` but `help(yaml.dump)` is not all too helpful, try `help(yaml.dump_all)` instead because `dump` is just a wrapper for `dump_all`.