# Python generate file YAML

Tags: python, list, dictionary, yaml

I need to generate a YAML file. There is the following dictionary `{'fruits': ['banana', 'apple'], 'car': [], 'clothes': ['jeans', 't-shirt', 'shirt'], 'headdress': [], 'shoes': []}`.

But I can't seem to generate the following file itself:

```yaml
config:
  product:
    fruits:
      name: Fruits
      object_types:
        fruits:
          goods:
            banana
              name: banana
            apple:
              name: apple
        name: Fruits
    car:
      name: Car
      object_types:
        car:
         goods: {}
         name: Car
    clothes:
      name: Clothes
      object_types:
        clothes:
          goods:
            jeans:
              name: Jeans
            t-shirt:
              name: T-shirt
            shirt:
              name: Shirt
          name: Clothes
    headdress:
      name: Headdress
      object_types:
        headdress:
          goods: {}
          name: Headdress
    shoes:
      name: Shoes
      object_types:
        shoes:
          goods: {}
          name: Shoes
```

I have a problem when I create a dictionary, view.

```
clothes:
  goods:
    jeans:
      name: Jeans
    t-shirt:
      name: T-shirt
    shirt:
      name: Shirt
  name: Clothes
```

As a result, my dictionary is being rewritten. As a result I have the following

```
clothes:
  goods:
    shirt:
      name: Shirt
  name: Clothes
```

my code

```
dict models = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple'], 'car': [], 'clothes': ['jeans', 't-shirt', 'shirt'], 'headdress': [], 'shoes': []}

# Generate a yaml file
for key, value in dict_models.items():
    main_models[key] = {key: {
        "name": str(key).title(),
        "object_types": {
            "goods":
                {key: {
                    "name": key.title()}}}}}

pprint.pprint(main_models )

with open("config.yaml", "w") as fw:
    yaml.dump(main_models, fw, default_flow_style=False)
```

Solution

To solve the task, I decided to simplify the solution

```
    for key,values in dict_models.items(): 
        goods_dict = {}
            for value in values:
                goods_dict[value] = {'name': value} 
            result[key] = goods_dict 
    
    for key, value in result.items():
        main_models[key] = { "name": str(key).title(), "object_types": {key: {"goods": value, "name": key.title()}}}
```

That's all. Thanks everyone for participating.

Comment: What have you tried, and how exactly has it failed? Without your best attempt, your question looks like "Write this code for me for free", which definitely isn't what SO is about.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. In addition to the above advice, does this question cover what you need to know? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file If so, you can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: It's completely unclear how is your Python dict supposed to be transformed into that YAML structure, which isn't even valid. Why is "Car" under "fruits"? Why are some dictionary keys duplicated? And indentation is all wrong.

Comment: @gre_gor
Sorry, I corrected the indentations.

I have added information

Comment: Hello, @Thierry Lathuille
I have added information. I need help creating a loop. I can't add a list of dictionaries inside the dictionary. The following type
```
         goods:
             jeans:
               name: Jeans
             t-shirt:
               name: T-shirt
             shirt:
               name: Shirt
           name: Clothes
```

Возможно я что то делаю не так, и мой словарь нужно переделать, но я не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: hi @morric Unfortunately this is not it

Comment: @Ilnaz Please add your current, not completely working code to your question.

Comment: dict models = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple'], 'car': [], 'clothes': ['jeans', 't-shirt', 'shirt'], 'headdress': [], 'shoes': []}

```
# Generate a yaml file
for key, value in dict_models.items():
    main_models[key] = {key: {
        "name": str(key).title(),
        "object_types": {
            "goods":
                {key: {
                    "name": key.title()}}}}}
print()
pprint.pprint(main_models )

with open("config.yaml", "w") as fw:
    yaml.dump(main_models, fw, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille
I added my code

Comment: To solve the task, I decided to simplify the solution
     
<pre><code>
for key,values in dict_models.items(): 
     goods_dict = {} 
         for value in values:goods_dict[value] = {'name': value} result[key] = goods_dict for key, value in result.items(): main_models[key] = { "name": str(key).title(), "object_types": {key: {"goods": value, "name": key.title()}}} That's all. Thanks everyone for participating.
</code>