Python script to read credentials from a yaml file, read a dataset and update information
I'm working on an academic project where I need to create a python script to change credentials from a yaml file. This script should read the yaml file, then look for the value of Oauth 1 in a spreadsheet (authentication column) and get the updated Oauth 2, finally create a new ymal file with auth 2. I would like to know where I can start.
I have a credentials.yaml with the content below.
      name: gcp_credentials_project
      info: 1798
      project_id: acd-univer-proj-mod-pers
      consumer_key: "cfb45ac0098b723f84219e5c12a9532067abf19a7"
      oauth_token: "52871f93b604e239a431de879b3c2e45082768f02d"
      oauth_version: 1.0
      oauth_signature_metho: "HMAC-SHA1"

The yaml file should be parsed and updated (oauth_version) as below.
      name: gcp_credentials_project
      info: 1798
      project_id: acd-univer-proj-mod-pers
      consumer_key: "cfb45ac0098b723f84219e5c12a9532067abf19a7"
      oauth_token: "52871f93b604e239a431de879b3c2e45082768f02d"
      oauth_version: 2.0
      oauth_signature_metho: "HMAC-SHA1"


There seems to be a number of questions here or alternatively, a request for a larger script that solves your entire task rather than addressing a single question or issue. This site is most effective at answering specific questions. Is there one question that you would like to address such as "How do I write a yaml file?"

Perhaps the big question is how to read the dataset and update the yaml file. I can read the yaml, but I can't advance in the part of reading the dataset and returning the data to update the yaml.

See if either of these can get you going https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239207/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-in-python and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file If they do, you might close this as a duplicate. If not, please edit your question to provide more details so people can more effectively help you.

Ok, thanks for the help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The quotes on the values for the keys consumer_key and oauth_token are superfluous.
If you need to preserve them, as you indicate, you'll find that is difficult to do with PyYAML.
Additionally PyYAML only suport YAML 1.1, outdated 15 years ago.
I recommend you use ruamel.yaml for this kind of round-tripping (read/modify/save) of YAML (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).
In addition to being able to preserve quotes, it preserves comments, handles keys that are collections and YAML 1.2
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

file_path = pathlib.Path('input.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(file_path)
data['oauth_version'] = 2.0
# This shows the content, on stdout. To update the file use: yaml.dump(data, file_path)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

which gives:
name: gcp_credentials_project
info: 1798
project_id: acd-univer-proj-mod-pers
consumer_key: "cfb45ac0098b723f84219e5c12a9532067abf19a7"
oauth_token: "52871f93b604e239a431de879b3c2e45082768f02d"
oauth_version: 2.0
oauth_signature_metho: "HMAC-SHA1"

The input and expected output you showed have leading spaces, which I assumed are because of unfamiliarity with SO formatting. If these spaces really need to be in the output, then can be added in a simple postprocessing step with the optional transform argument of dump().
