# How do I install the yaml package for Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pip, pyyaml

I have a Python program that uses YAML.  I attempted to install it on a new server using `pip install yaml` and it returns the following:

```
$ sudo pip install yaml
Downloading/unpacking yaml
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement yaml
No distributions at all found for yaml
Storing complete log in /home/pa/.pip/pip.log
```

How do I install the yaml package for Python?  I'm running Python 2.7.  (OS: Debian Wheezy)

Comment: add information on which platform do you use. libyaml. http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML is not pure python package, it may cause different installation.

Comment: For anyone else on the confusion of naming, `pip install pyyaml` imports as `import yaml` inside your actual script.

Answer (score 759, accepted):

You could try the search the feature on https://pypi.org/search (via a browser) and look for packages in PyPI with yaml in the short description.  That reveals various packages, including PyYaml, yamltools, and PySyck, among others (Note that [PySyck docs](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PySyck) recommend using PyYaml, since syck is out of date).  Now you know a specific package name, you can install it:

```
$ pip install pyyaml
```

If you want to install python yaml system-wide in linux, you can also use a package manager, like `aptitude` or `yum`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-yaml
$ sudo yum install python-yaml
```

Comment: The name of the PyYAML package at least on Fedora 21 and CentOS 7 is just `PyYAML` not `python-yaml`.

Comment: PyYAML implements the old YAML 1.1 spec from 2004 (Syck the even older 1.0 spec). ruamel.yaml is now the non-out-of-date package that implements the YAML1.2 specification

Comment: So what if I am on a system with neither pip nor a package manager?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger you can [get python](https://www.python.org/downloads/), [get pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), [build LibYAML from source](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML), and finally [install PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). LibYAML is not strictly required as PyYAML will work with pure python (albeit slower)

Comment: thanks a lot ,your answer have solved my question entirely.

Comment: I had to install it "system wide" using `apt`. With `pip` it was not working

Comment: You teach how to catch a fish, instead of giving it away :) Thanks!

Comment: The `pip search yaml` prints out 102 lines, none of which actually included the `pyyaml` package name, even though `pip install pyyaml` *does* work. Going through all those lines would have taken 50 times more than searching "pip install yaml" on Google. Not your fault, but unfortunately, today you are in 99% of the cases better off asking an internet search engine instead of using the intended lookup tools (also applies to `man`, for example). Thanks for showing how to do it anyway.

Comment: @phil294 you are right - it is a shame.  When I wrote this answer in 2013, there were about 10 results for `yaml` in PyPI; today there are >4500; >750 matches for "pyyaml".  In the comments to [how does pip search work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269282), we find that pip only returns the first 100 results, due to the PyPI api.  But that is an explanation for the problem, not a method to solve the issue of selecting an appropriate package sadly.  Would be v happy for suggestions of what to incorporate in the answer

Comment: Wow - ten years and a day since this question was asked and nothing's changed.

Comment: There was a change, @keithpjolley: `pip` doesn't allow search anymore. :D Another point is that many pytonistas seeem to prefer `ruamel.yaml`, instead of `pyyaml`.

Comment: just as a small note: `pip search` seems no longer to be supported - instead, it is recommended to search online with a browser after navigating to `https://pypi.org/search`

Answer (score 128):

`pip install pyyaml`

If you don't have pip, run `easy_install pip` to install pip, which is the go-to package installer - [Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).  If you prefer to stick with easy_install, then `easy_install pyyaml`

Answer (score 75):

#### This answers if for MacOS

**Update:** Nowadays installing is done with pip, and for many users [a wheel](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels) may be available (depending on your Mac and required version of [PyYaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#files)). In some cases [libyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML) is still required to build the C extension (on mac); this can be done with:

```sh
brew install libyaml
python -m pip install pyyaml
```

---

*Outdated method*:

For MacOSX (mavericks), the following works:

```sh
brew install libyaml
sudo python -m easy_install pyyaml
```

Comment: This is the only working answer for OS X Yosemite when I tried.

Comment: This worked for me on Yosemite, but only with brew's python 2.7.9, not OS X python 2.7.6.

Comment: This was the only working answer for OS X Lion when I tried. Thanks  so much! I thought it wasn't working because I was using a 2011 operating system in 2020.

Answer (score 25):

```
pip install PyYAML
```

If libyaml is not found or compiled PyYAML can do without it on Mavericks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I got the error `libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml` when using `sudo pip install PyYAML`. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: However, I said `Successfully installed PyYAML`. See [pip-PyYAML](http://i1.tietuku.com/896d50da2caf8e06.png) for complete information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

There are three YAML capable packages. Syck (`pip install syck`) which implements the YAML 1.0 specification from 2002; PyYAML (`pip install pyyaml`) which follows the YAML 1.1 specification from 2004; and [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) which follows the latest (YAML 1.2, from 2009) specification.

You can install the YAML 1.2 compatible package with `pip install ruamel.yaml` or if you are running a modern version of Debian/Ubuntu (or derivative) with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-ruamel.yaml
```

Answer (score 10):

following command will download `pyyaml`, which also includes `yaml`

```
pip install pyYaml
```

Answer (score 8):

Debian-based systems:

`$ sudo aptitude install python-yaml`

or newer for python3

`$ sudo aptitude install python3-yaml`

Answer (score 6):

"There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it." So let me add another one. This one is more like "install from sources" for Debian/Ubuntu, from https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml

Install the libYAML and it's headers:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

[Download](http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml) the pyyaml sources:

```
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz
```

Install from sources, (don't forget to activate your venv):

```
. your/env/bin/activate
tar xzf PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz
cd PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz
(env)$ python setup.py install
(env)$ python setup.py test
```

Comment: This was the only method that led me to correctly install the CLoaders on MacOS. I previously tried `brew install libyaml & pip install pyyaml`
but, `python -c 'from yaml import CSafeLoader'` kept failing

Answer (score 4):

## Consider using [strictyaml](https://pypi.org/project/strictyaml/) instead

If you have the luxury of creating the yaml file yourself, or if you don't require [any of these features](https://hitchdev.com/strictyaml/features-removed/) of regular yaml, I recommend using [`strictyaml`](https://pypi.org/project/strictyaml/) instead of the standard `pyyaml` package.

In short, default yaml has some serious flaws in terms of security, interface, and predictability. `strictyaml` is a subset of the yaml spec that does not have those issues (and is better documented).

You can read more about the [problems with regular yaml here](https://arp242.net/yaml-config.html)

**OPINION:** `strictyaml` should be the default implementation of yaml and the old yaml spec should be obsoleted.

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing development version of libyaml did it.

```
yum install libyaml-devel         #centos
apt-get install libyaml-dev       # ubuntu
```

Comment: Please, include explanations that it's system-wide Python installation, tha tit's x86-64 architecture, that there should be similar command for APT...

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Done

Comment: @MayankJaiswal How would you install the development version for Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

## ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2

pip install pyyaml

## ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

pip3 install pyyaml

## ️ if you get permissions error

sudo pip3 install pyyaml

## ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable

python -m pip install pyyaml

## ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

python3 -m pip install pyyaml

## ️ for Anaconda

conda install -c conda-forge pyyaml

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Python scripts with `sudo` and facing module import errors, it's likely due to `sudo` not preserving the `PYTHONPATH` from your Conda environment. To fix this, explicitly set the `PYTHONPATH` to include your Conda environment's `site-packages` directory before running your script with `sudo`. Here's how:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH="/home/enviornment_name/miniconda3/envs/car/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in pip3 install yaml or like Connor pip3 install strictyaml

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You shouldn't answer old questions, especially if they already have 10 answers and are pretty old, unless you have something important to add, which does not seem the case here. Provide answers to newer questions, that way you will also be able to comment on posts (once you have sufficient reputation)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to asking on Stackoverflow

Comment: Don't worry, in February I was exactly where you are now... it takes some time to get used to the system but you can profit from it a lot : )

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me because I didn't have root privileges on the machine I was working on. A colleague suggested the below command which worked. This installs the pyyaml package for the current logged in user.

```
python3 -m pip install --user PyYAML
```