# Trying to load in a two dictionaries as JSON files but cant load in the second file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two JSON files that I am trying to load in python

**queue.json**

```
[
    ["Person 1", "B"],
    ["Person 2", "C"],
    ["Person 3", "A"],
    ["Person 4", "B"],
    ["Person 5", "C"],
]
```

**and stock.json**

```
 {
   "A": 5, 
   "B": 3, 
   "C": 10
 }
```

I'm using this code to load in the stock file

```
 import json

 # Load the stock file.
 stock = json.load(open("stock.json"))
```

but when I use this code to load in the queue file it says that no JSON object could be coded:

```
 import json
 # Load the queue file.

 queue = json.load(open("queue.json"))
```

Comment: Yes, this is python, sorry i've only started learning the program

Comment: queue.json is not valid json. You can test if it is valid json by running a sample in https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the content of the JSON file. Try changing the `queue.json` to

```
[
    {"B":"Person 1"},
    {"C":"Person 2"},
    {"A":"Person 3"},
    {"B":"Person 4"},
    {"C":"Person 5"}
]
```

Comment: the letters in stock are supposed to represent the medicine that person 1 2 3 4 and 5 are queuing for, i need to write a program that will give medicine to the people queuing and then update the amount of the stock file once it has gone through the list of people queuing and given them the medicine they need. the way the json file is set out is the way i have been given it in

Comment: I updated the answer, in that json, you can easily determine which medicine is used and just add a +1 on the stock for every queue finished

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid json:

```
[
    ["Person 1", "B"],
    ["Person 2", "C"],
    ["Person 3", "A"],
    ["Person 4", "B"],
    ["Person 5", "C"],
]
```

The problem is the trailing comma on the list.  One solution is to use `yaml` instead.  `yaml` is a superset of `json`, and will accept the comma.

```
import yaml
queue = yaml.load(open(""queue.json"))
```

Comment: when i do that it comes up "ImportError: No module named yaml"

Comment: You will need to install yaml, if you want to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python#14262462