# How to install PyYAML

Tags: python, installation, yaml, python-3.5, pyyaml

I want to install PyYAML for a project and all I can find is a link to the http://pyyaml.org/ site. I downloaded the python 3.5 exe file and it says "Python 3.5 version required, which was not found in the registry"

I searched on other ways on installing it. The only other one I found on stack overflow was "$ pip install pyyaml". It does not say where the command should be used to install the package.

Answer (score 2):

PyYAML requires python version 3.4 or greater.  Make certain you meet that requirement.

### `pip`

- At the interpreter or command prompt you can:

```py
pip install pyyaml
```

### `conda`

```py
# at the anaconda prompt
conda install -c anaconda pyyaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I installed python 3.6.1 and used the command `pip install pyyaml` in windows command prompt. It downloaded and install PyYAML.

Answer (score 1):

You saw a "Python X.Y version required, which was not found in the registry" message because the .exe installer for the PyYAML package you downloaded was either expecting a different version of Python, a version of Python with a different bitness or both. The installer will expect the same bitness of Python it was built with.

If all you had was the installer for PyYAML you would be forced to find a version of Python which matches the bitness of the installer for PyYAML. The compiler string that's printed when you start Python from the command line will give you some insight into the platform your version of Python was built for.

Answer (score 1):

On of the way to install python yaml system-wide in linux, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python/14262462):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-yaml
```

Also, this could be possible:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Into the code:

```
...
import yaml
...
```

This helped me!