# Use docker compose push to push one image with multiple tags

Tags: docker-compose

Now that `docker-compose` v1 is deprecated in favor of `docker compose` v2, and the Compose file `build` section supports [a `tags` subsection](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#tags), how can I use the old equivalent of `docker-compose push` to push all the images? Say I have this example docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
---
version: "3"

services:

  myservice:
    image: myregistry.com/stuff/myimage:v1.0.0
    build:
      context: ./myimage
      tags:
        - myregistry.com/stuff/myimage:latest
```

If I follow `docker compose build` with `docker compose push`, only the v1.0.0 tag gets pushed. Is there an alternative other than falling back to `docker push myregistry.com/stuff/myimage:latest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just investigating the same issue and happened upon your post.

As referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658034) the code added to handle building with multiple tags [was merged into docker compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9481) on 05/23/2022 (so relatively recent).  `docker compose push` doesn't appear to respect that yet.

However, you can use the `--all-tags` flag to `docker push` to push all tags of an image which appears to accomplish close to the same objective.

> -a, --all-tags                Push all tags of an image to the repository

```
docker push --all-tags myregistry.com/stuff/myimage
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is probably the closest I can get until compose includes the old functionality. Thanks!