# PyCharm, can not import modules

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to import

```
1.yaml
2.pypiper
```

modules to the latest `PyCharm` IDE. I can not find `pypiper` in the list of available modules. When I am trying to add a new repository for the `pypiper`:

https://github.com/epigen/pypiper.git

still the same: typing `pypiper` in the search field does not yield anything.

`yaml` at the same time can be found, but it is giving me an error when I am trying to add it:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for yaml
```

Comment: Did you try `pip install yaml` and `pip install pypiper` in the command line?

Comment: Yes, I did it, but not working

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm looks for packages in the repositories that it has been told to look in. By default it looks at `https://pypi.python.org/simple`.

Effectively this means that if you cannot install something through pip, you cannot install through the PyCharm interface.

What you need to do is to figure out:

1. [How to install yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python)

`sudo pip install pyyaml`

2. [How to install pypiper](https://github.com/epigen/pypiper)

`pip install --user https://github.com/epigen/pypiper/zipball/master`

When I run into these issues it's easiest for me to just install on the command line opposed to through `PyCharm` unless it's a virtual env. Just make sure your `pip` is referencing the same python interpreter you are using in `PyCharm` or you still wont see it in PyCharm.

Comment: Somehow these do not solve the issue. Both pyyaml and pypiper are installed. python version is correct (2.7), but things are not working.