# import yaml missing error module

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyyaml

```
 >>> import yaml   
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/tools/python_libs/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   from error import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'error'
```

I don't see how to set my PYTHONPATH with anaconda3.

Am I missing an install step?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation, but with the ROS. The same error reproduces when you use python 3 instead of python 2. You can see corresponding discussion
[here](https://answers.ros.org/question/314971/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-error/). For some reasons I would like to use python3 instead of python2, so I need to find out, how to get rid of this error.

I can suggest two solutions right now:

1. Either use python2 instead of python3, as suggested in [ROS discussion](https://answers.ros.org/question/314971/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-error/)
2. Or try to install `yaml` with `pip3` for python3 (not `pip`). I think it may help in this situation. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python) for installation instructions.