# pip3 install PyYAML failed.(python3.7, macOS High Sierra)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I've upgraded python3.7 with `brew upgrade` command.

And I've tried to install PyYAML package with `pip3`.

I've got this error and have no idea..

```
% pip3 install PyYAML

    checking if libyaml is linkable
    clang build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/check_libyaml.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -lyaml -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/check_libyaml
    building '_yaml' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/ext
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c ext/_yaml.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/ext/_yaml.o
    In file included from ext/_yaml.c:271:
    ext/_yaml.h:10:9: warning: 'PyString_CheckExact' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define PyString_CheckExact PyBytes_CheckExact
            ^
    ext/_yaml.c:139:11: note: previous definition is here
      #define PyString_CheckExact          PyUnicode_CheckExact
              ^
    ext/_yaml.c:1410:17: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_v_value = yaml_get_version_string();
                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ext/_yaml.c:2577:52: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (void *, char *, size_t, size_t *)' (aka 'int (void *, char *, unsigned long, unsigned long *)') to parameter of type 'yaml_read_handler_t *' (aka 'int (*)(void *, unsigned char *, unsigned long, unsigned long *)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        yaml_parser_set_input((&__pyx_v_self->parser), __pyx_f_5_yaml_input_handler, ((void *)__pyx_v_self));
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/yaml.h:1370:30: note: passing argument to parameter 'handler' here 

.......
```

And finally

```
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    51 warnings and 15 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-exbgmayz/PyYAML/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-n11vy5s0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-exbgmayz/PyYAML/
```

I've tried solve this problem, but still have no idea.

- https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/126
- [How do I install the yaml package for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python)

How can I resolve this issue..?

Comment: "May I help you..?" is asking if **you** can offer help to someone else. You probably want to ask something like "How can I resolve this issue?" What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Oh.. Thank you for let me know sir.

Comment: check the workaround suggested in https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/152

Answer (score 7):

PyYAML's C extension do not compile on 3.7, that is what the error message is about and what some messages in the thread of issue 126 refer to. There is a mechanism in the PyYAML installer that should test if the C extension can be compiled, it mostly checks if libyaml is available.

I assumed you upgraded to 3.7.0 (instead of upgrading Python3.7 as you write) so I suggest you downgrade to 3.6. Although PyYAML's page on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), indicates that only 3.4 and 3.5 are supported, 3.6 seems to be fine.

If you can't downgrade Python, and need the functionality of 3.7 now, you can consider using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). It is essentially a superset of PyYAML, so normally doing

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
```

should get your program working. Since macOS wheels for 3.7 are available on PyPI installation should not cause any problems.

Comment: Thank you sir, I've downloaded to python3.6.0. 
And It works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.7 breaks the build for PyYaml. Use Python 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

yaml didnt work with python 3.7

Fix: downgrade to python2 and install yaml

1. brew install python@2.
2. brew install libyaml
3. sudo python -m easy_install pyyaml.

Comment: why would a person who needs python3.X install 2.X to solve an issue?