# How to add yaml to php server docker installation

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I am having problems installing yaml support on my php docker configuraiton.
Here is my dockerbuild file:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
# Install YAML extension
RUN  pecl install yaml && echo "extension=yaml.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-yaml.ini && docker-php-ext-enable yaml
```

But I am getting error:

```
configure: error: Please install libyaml
```

I googled, but haven`t found working solution yet. Any ideas how should I do it?

Note:

```
RUN apt-get install libyaml
```

Havent worked, got message `E: Unable to locate package libyaml`

And also this command havent worked:

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

error: `yum install libyaml-devel`

Comment: Have you tried `RUN apt-get install libyaml-dev`?

Comment: @John got this erorr E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found also different way, maybe for someone easier because adding php extension is really simple.
https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

And here is my final `Dockerfile`

```
   FROM php:7.2.2-apache
    ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
    RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
        install-php-extensions mysqli yaml
```

Answer (score 6):

First you need to run the update and then install the required package that is `libyaml-dev`.

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
# Install YAML extension
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libyaml-dev -y
RUN  pecl install yaml && echo "extension=yaml.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-yaml.ini && docker-php-ext-enable yaml
```

[How do I install the yaml package for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python)