# How to install YAML package in Pycharm (Python 3.8 / 3.9)?

Tags: pip, pycharm, yaml

How do I install the YAML package in Pycharm? I want to use it for a python 3.8 (or 3.9) project. When trying to install the package via the project settings I get the following error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml`

Alternatively I tried to search for any YAML package available via the command window by typing `pip search yaml`. Then I get the following error:

`ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]`

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: PyPI's API is currently disabled, the search won't work, see https://status.python.org/

Comment: What is the name of the package you're trying to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the yaml package for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261614/how-do-i-install-the-yaml-package-for-python)

Comment: The package is called "yaml" (no further extensions to the naming) It´s used in a example python project from github.

Comment: That example looks wrong, I can't find that package: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for yaml`. Please share the link to the project.

Answer (score 10):

`pip install pyyaml`

I think that this is what you are looking for: https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

It gets imported as `import yaml`