# Reading YAML file with Python results in yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a yaml file that looks like

```
---
level_1: "test"
level_2: 'NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation'
request: 341570
---
level_1: "test"
level_2: 'NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation'
request: 341569
---
level_1: "test"
level_2: 'NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation'
request: 341568
```

I am able to read this correctly in Perl using YAML but not in python using YAML. It fails with the error:

> expected a single document in the stream

Program:

```py
import yaml

stram = open("test", "r")
print yaml.load(stram)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abcd", line 4, in <module>
    print yaml.load(stram)
  File "/usr/local/pkgs/python-2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 58, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/pkgs/python-2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 42, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/local/pkgs/python-2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 43, in get_single_node
    event.start_mark)
yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream
  in "test", line 2, column 1
but found another document
  in "test", line 5, column 1
```

Comment: For reference see chapter 2 (syntax) of http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html. It is a 5 mn read and worth it.

Comment: See [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054860/562769)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The yaml documents are separated by `---`, and if any stream (e.g. a file) contains more than one document then you should use the `yaml.load_all` function rather than `yaml.load`.  The code:

```py
import yaml

stream = open("test", "r")
docs = yaml.load_all(stream, yaml.FullLoader)
for doc in docs:
    for k,v in doc.items():
        print k, "->", v
    print "\n",
```

results in for the input file as provided in the question:

```
request -> 341570
level_1 -> test
level_2 -> NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation

request -> 341569
level_1 -> test
level_2 -> NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation

request -> 341568
level_1 -> test
level_2 -> NetApp, SOFS, ZFS Creation
```

Comment: This answer works. For future posterity, they are using the PyYAML module, so you must `pip install pyyaml` for it to work.

Comment: just for reference: according to https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation `yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)` is recommended

Comment: There's also `yaml.safe_load_all(stream)`  which is better for loading .yml files that you've not written yourself, as it prevents executing arbitrary code.