# extract a dictionary key value from a string

Tags: python, string, list

I am currently in the process of using python to transmit a python dictionary from one raspberry pi to another over a 433Mhz link, using virtual wire (vw.py) to send data.

The issue with `vw.py` is that data being sent is in string format.

I am successfully receiving the data on PI_no2, and now I am trying to reformat the data so it can be placed back in a dictionary.

I have created a small snippet to test with, and created a temporary string in the same format it is received as from vw.py

So far I have successfully split the string at the colon, and I am now trying to get rid of the double quotes, without much success.

```
my_status = {}
#temp is in the format the data is recieved
temp = "'mycode':['1','2','firstname','Lastname']"

key,value = temp.split(':')
print key
print value

key = key.replace("'",'')
value = value.replace("'",'')

my_status.update({key:value})

print my_status
```

Gives the result

```
'mycode'
['1','2','firstname','Lastname']
{'mycode': '[1,2,firstname,Lastname]'}
```

I require the value to be in the format

```
['1','2','firstname','Lastname']
```

but the strip gets rid of all the single speech marks.

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval`, maybe add `{` and `}` to the beginning and end so it's a dictionary but that would evaluate it safely

Comment: Have you tried using JSON?

Comment: or you could [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) your data for more complex (but python specific) data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
temp = "'mycode':['1','2','firstname','Lastname']"
key,value = map(ast.literal_eval, temp.split(':'))
status = {key: value}
```

Will output

```
{'mycode': ['1', '2', 'firstname', 'Lastname']}
```

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be hard to solve. What you need to do is `strip` away the `[ ]` in your list string, then `split` by `,`. Once you've done this, iterate over the elements are add them to a list. Your code should look like this:

```
string = "[1,2,firstname,lastname]"
string = string.strip("[")
string = string.strip("]")
values = string.split(",")
final_list = []
for val in values:
    final_list.append(val)
print final_list
```

This will return:

```
> ['1','2','firstname','lastname']
```

Then take this list and insert it into your dictionary:

```
 d = {}
 d['mycode'] = final_list
```

The advantage of this method is that you can handle each value independently. If you need to convert `1` and `2` to `int` then you'll be able to do that while leaving the other two as `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to cricket_007's suggestion of using a syntax tree parser - you're format is very similar to the standard [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359557/reading-yaml-in-python) format. This is a pretty lightweight and intutive framework so I'll suggest it

```
a = "'mycode':['1','2','firstname','Lastname']"
print yaml.load(a.replace(":",": "))
# prints the dictionary {'mycode': ['1', '2', 'firstname', 'Lastname']}
```

The only thing that's different between your format and yaml is the colon needs a space

It also will distinguish between primitive data types for you, if that's important. Drop the quotes around `1` and `2` and it determines that they're numerical.

Tadhg McDonald-Jensen suggested [pickling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-python-pickle-file) in the comments. This will allow you to store more complicated objects, though you may lose the human-readable format you've been experimenting with