# PyYAML dump format

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, quotes, pyyaml

I know there are a few questions about this on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I'm using [pyyaml](http://pyyaml.org) to read (`.load()`) a `.yml` file, modify or add a key, and then write it (`.dump()`) again. The problem is that I want to keep the file format post-dump, but it changes.

For example, I edit the key `en.test.index.few` to say `"Bye"` instead of `"Hello"`.

**Python:**

```python
with open(path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as yaml_file:
    self.dict = yaml.load(yaml_file)
```

Then, after changing the key:

```python
with open(path, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as yaml_file:
    dump = pyyaml.dump(self.dict, default_flow_style = False, allow_unicode = True, encoding = None)
    yaml_file.write( dump )
```

**Yaml:**

*Before:*

```yaml
en:
  test:
    new: "Bye"
    index:
      few: "Hello"
  anothertest: "Something"
```

*After:*

```yaml
en:
  anothertest: Something
  test:
    index:
      few: Hello
    new: Bye
```

Is there a way to keep the same format?
For example the qoutes and order. Am I using the wrong tool for this?

I know maybe the original file it's not entirely correct, but I have no control over it (it's a Ruby-on-Rails i18n file).

Thank you very much.

Comment: `yaml.dump` has a `default_style` argument. Using `default_style='"'` will keep your string values in double quotes, but your keys and any other value types will also be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks!, I'll keep it in mind, it would have been really useful if it wasn't for the keys :(

Comment: You'll probably have a hard time ordering the keys, too. `yaml.load` gives you a `dict`; its keys are unordered. `yaml.dump` probably outputs in whatever order the iteration goes.

Comment: The new file represents exactly the same information (in YAML) as the origin file; there is no reason to keep the same format.

Comment: @Evert that's true, but I wanted to keep the format because it's useful given the context of the sublime package I have created https://github.com/NicoSantangelo/sublime-text-i18n-rails

Comment: It's possible to maintain the ordering of the keys now, using the `sort_keys=False` parameter in `yaml.dump()`

Answer (score 113):

Below, [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) is used instead.

`ruamel.yaml` is [actively maintained](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/). Unlike PyYAML, `ruamel.yaml` supports:

- **YAML <= 1.2.** PyYAML only supports YAML <= 1.1. This is vital, as YAML 1.2 intentionally [breaks backward compatibility](https://yaml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyyaml.html#defaulting-to-yaml-1-2-support) with YAML 1.1 in several edge cases. This would usually be a bad thing. In this case, this renders YAML 1.2 a strict superset of JSON. Since YAML 1.1 is *not* a strict superset of JSON, this is a good thing.
- **Roundtrip preservation.** When calling `yaml.dump()` to dump a dictionary loaded by a prior call to `yaml.load()`:

  - PyYAML naively ignores all input formatting – including comments, ordering, quoting, and whitespace. Discarded like so much digital refuse into the nearest available bit bucket.
  - `ruamel.yaml` cleverly respects *all* input formatting. Everything. The whole stylistic enchilada. The entire literary shebang. **All.**

### Library Migration

Switching from PyYAML to `ruamel.yaml` in existing applications is typically as simple as changing the library import to:

```
from ruamel import yaml
```

This works because `ruamel.yaml` is a PyYAML fork that conforms to the PyYAML API.

No other changes should be needed. The `yaml.load()` and `yaml.dump()` functions should continue to behave as expected.

### Roundtrip Preservation and What It Can Do for You

For backward compatibility with PyYaml, the `yaml.load()` and `yaml.dump()` functions do *not* perform roundtrip preservation by default. To do so, explicitly pass:

- The optional `Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader` keyword parameter to `yaml.load()`.
- The optional `Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper` keyword parameter to `yaml.dump()`.

An example kindly "borrowed" from [`ruamel.yaml` documentation](http://yaml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html):

```
import ruamel.yaml

inp = """\
# example
name:
  # Yet another Great Duke of Hell. He's not so bad, really.
  family: TheMighty
  given: Ashtaroth
"""

code = ruamel.yaml.load(inp, Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
code['name']['given'] = 'Astarte'  # Oh no you didn't.

print(ruamel.yaml.dump(code, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper), end='')
```

**It is done.** Comments, ordering, quoting, and whitespace will now be preserved intact.

Comment: I must say this is a wonderful answer. I'm currently not developing the project that used PyYAML but I'll definitely give `ruamel.yaml` a try when I have some spare time and accept the answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: It actually doesn't maintain all formatting.  For instance, quotes are not kept.

Comment: @sjmh If `ruamel.yaml` fails to roundtrip preserve _any_ formatting (including but not limited to quote style), **that's a bug.** Consider submitting an issue at `ruamel.yaml`'s [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues?status=new&status=open). The [principal maintainer](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/) of `ruamel.yaml` is quite receptive and friendly, thankfully. Cheers!

Comment: @sjmh Starting with ruamel.yaml 0.11.12 you can specify `preserve_quotes=True` during loading, which will wrap the strings loaded with information needed for dumping. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38582476/1307905)

Comment: @Anthon Will it somehow preserve blank lines between data?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Yes it will. Empty lines are considered comments without `#` and are preserved. But in case you'll be inserting new values, beware that the comments/empty lines are currently attached to mapping-keys/sequence-elements **before** the comment (i.e. comment gathering is greedy), even though visually the might be "closer" to the following key/element

Comment: That's great to hear.  I have a bunch of issues and I'll raise them in Bitbucket.  Your project is fantastic, it's almost unbelievable no one has thought of it before!

Comment: Is this comment still up to date with [the current state of PyYAML?](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml)

Comment: PyYAML has new maintainers now, and had a v4.1 release recently. The answer is outdated and silly content such as "PyYAML is a fetid corpse rotting.." should probably be edited out.

Comment: @wim aaaand PyYAML development grinded to a halt again, with no meaningful changes since 5 months. The 4.1 release [broke](https://github.com/TankerHQ/tsrc/commit/f7fb55a5c540856560106b9e13ce3a6c347979a5) [many](https://github.com/heilaaks/snippy/commit/d81e82e1113daca6575f4e891397e480e69d6249) [projects](https://github.com/fecgov/openFEC/issues/3280), and we are currently sitting on 4.2b4, which is pretty embarrassing. There is little hope that it ever gets a proper release and lots of regret for not choosing ruamel in the first place.

Comment: 3.x to 4.x is a major version number bump, so backwards incompat changes should be expected. I'm not denying PyYAML maintainership has problems and politics, but the language used in this answer is a bit excessive. It reads like an advertisement for ruamel.yaml or propaganda.

Comment: Still dead. Never trust one release, only a pattern of releases. Long live ruamel.yaml

Comment: I am afraid the "new" PyYAML is very lacking from the point of view of usability in a Python environment. Some "maintainers" are tinkering around while they admittedly "learn Python". And they fight fiercely against obvious requests like preserving dictionary order just like Python does. It is a pity for such a relevant project.

Comment: while ruamel works better, its also faulty. The state of yaml loading + dumping in python is unfortunately quite bad.

Comment: ruamel.yaml is significantlly slower than pyyaml.
Something to keep in mind

Comment: This answer should be corrected.
It immediately starts with false statements. Maybe they where true at the time it was written, but it is not longer the case.
PyYaml is not dead and the web site is up.
At the moment of writing this comment, PyYaml appear quite alive and kicking.
Look at the latest releases:

- 2019-07-30: PyYAML 5.1.2 is released.
- 2018-06-06: PyYAML 5.1.1 is released.
- 2019-03-13: LibYAML 0.2.2 and PyYAML 5.1 are released.
- 2018-07-05: PyYAML 3.13 is released.
- 2018-06-24: LibYAML 0.2.1 is released.

This answer is misleading.

Comment: The PyYAML source code can now be found at https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml , and shows quite some activity (in commits, issues & responses, and pull requests & merges). Perhaps these are all bad, but PyYAML is currently not unmaintained and dead.

Comment: While PyYAML is maintained and works well, the other library advertised here is questionable at best. The link is not even valid anymore, the project migrated from bitbucket to sourceforge and has very little activity over there.

Comment: I only edited it to remove language that was not appropriate for the SO.  Some of it showed terrible lack of understanding of history. I can't endorse the library, or the recommendations in this post.

Comment: FWIW, PyYAML managed to convert our Git commit 45433e8 into 4543300000000 and broke our CI. The respective PR https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/174 is stalled since 2018. https://www.openhub.net/p/_compare?project_0=ruamel-yaml&project_1=PyYAML gave us enough confidence to make the switch to ruamel.yaml.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I want `"` if value contains a `{` or a `}`, otherwise nothing. For example:

```
 en:
   key1: value is 1
   key2: 'value is {1}'
```

To perform that, copy function `represent_str()` from file *representer.py* in module PyYaml and use another style if string contains `{` or a `}`:

```
def represent_str(self, data):
    tag = None
    style = None
    # Add these two lines:
    if '{' in data or '}' in data:
        style = '"'
    try:
        data = unicode(data, 'ascii')
        tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        try:
            data = unicode(data, 'utf-8')
            tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            data = data.encode('base64')
            tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:binary'
            style = '|'
    return self.represent_scalar(tag, data, style=style)
```

To use it in your code:

```
import yaml

def represent_str(self, data):
  ...

yaml.add_representer(str, represent_str)
```

In this case, no diffences between keys and values and that's enough for me. If you want a different style for keys and values, perform the same thing with function `represent_mapping`

Answer (score 2):

**First**

To represent dictionary data is used following code:

```
mapping = list(mapping.items())
    try:
        mapping = sorted(mapping)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

It is why ordering is changed

**Second**

Information about how scalar type was presented (with double quote or not) is lost when reading (this is principal approach of library)

**Summary**

You can create own class based on 'Dumper' and to overload method 'represent_mapping' for changing behaviour how dictionary will be presented

For saving information about double quotes for scalar you must also create own class based on 'Loader', but i am afraid that it will affect and other classes and will doing it difficult