# pyyaml and using quotes for strings only

Tags: python, quotes, pyyaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
---
my_vars:
  my_env: "dev"
  my_count: 3
```

When I read it with PyYAML and dump it again, I get the following output:

```
---
my_vars:
  my_env: dev
  my_count: 3
```

The code in question:

```
with open(env_file) as f:
    env_dict = yaml.load(f)
    print(yaml.dump(env_dict, indent=4, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True))
```

I tried using the `default_style` parameter:

```
with open(env_file) as f:
    env_dict = yaml.load(f)
    print(yaml.dump(env_dict, indent=4, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True, default_style='"'))
```

But now I get:

```
---
"my_vars":
  "my_env": "dev"
  "my_count": !!int "3"
```

What do I need to do to keep the original formatting, **without** making any assumptions about the variable names in the YAML file?

Comment: Why don't you just print the file, is it important that you use the dictionary as the source for what you're printing and not the file itself?

Comment: I will add additional keys to the dictionary in the future, but the layout needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you update to using YAML 1.2 (released in 2009) with the backwards compatible [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) package instead of using PyYAML which implements most of YAML 1.1 (2005). (Disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

Then you just specify `preserve_quotes=True` when loading for round-tripping the YAML file:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
my_vars:
  my_env: "dev"    # keep "dev" quoted
  my_count: 3
"""
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
ruamel.yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which outputs (including the preserved comment):

```
---
my_vars:
  my_env: "dev"    # keep "dev" quoted
  my_count: 3
```

After loading the string scalars will be a subclass of string, to be able to accommodate the quoting info, but will work like a normal string for all other purposes. If you want to replace such a string though (`dev` to `fgw`)
you have to cast the string to this subclass ( `DoubleQuotedScalarString` from `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring`).

When round-tripping `ruamel.yaml` by default preserves the order (by insertion) of the keys.

Answer (score 9):

Right, so borrowing heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640959/how-can-i-control-what-scalar-form-pyyaml-uses-for-my-data), you can do something like this:

```
import yaml

# define a custom representer for strings
def quoted_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')

yaml.add_representer(str, quoted_presenter)


env_file = 'input.txt'
with open(env_file) as f:
    env_dict = yaml.load(f)
    print yaml.dump(env_dict, default_flow_style=False)
```

However, this just overloads it on *all* strings types in the dictionary so it'll quote the keys as well, not just the values.

It prints:

```
"my_vars":
  "my_count": 3
  "my_env": "dev"
```

Is this what you want? Not sure what you mean by variable names, do you mean the keys?

Comment: This already helped me a lot, thanks :-) Still not sure how I can apply it only on the values, not the keys.

Comment: If you have lots of spare time, then I suggest a trip to yaml's [documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers) on how to create representers and then a thorough read of YAML's tags [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). There's also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805418/pyyaml-dump-format) that discusses a fork of PyYaml and it does mention something about keeping the original formatting, might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the following method to retain your `double quoted scalar` object in `yaml`:

Taking your yaml example:

```
---
my_vars:
  my_env: "dev"
  my_count: 3
```

Loading it into an env_dict (dictionary):

```
myyaml = '''
---
my_vars:
  my_env: "dev"
  my_count: 3
'''

env_dict = yaml.load(myyaml, yaml.FullLoader) # loading yaml

print(env_dict)
{'my_vars': {'my_env': 'dev', 'my_count': 3}}

# Define a quoted class, which uses style = '"' and add representer to yaml

class quoted(str):
    pass

def quoted_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')
yaml.add_representer(quoted, quoted_presenter)


# Now, we update the dictionary env_dict as follows for the "dev" 
# value which needs to be a double quoted scalar

env_dict['my_vars'].update(my_env = quoted("dev")) # this makes "dev"
# a double quoted scalar

# Now, we dump the yaml as before

yaml.dump(env_dict, sys.stdout, indent=4, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True)

# which outputs

---
my_vars:
    my_count: 3
    my_env: "dev"
```

These links helped me to arrive at this answer : [Any yaml libraries in Python that support dumping of long strings as block literals or folded blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863889/8030107)

[How can I control what scalar form PyYAML uses for my data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8641732/8030107)

Also, this one is a great article to read on [To Quote or not to Quote?](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html)

Hope, this helps!