# Outputting yaml in dict format

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a list of dict that looks like this

```
data = {'items': [{'id': '1', 'desc': 'Item 1', 'cat': 'cat1'}], 'categories': [{ 'id': 'cat1', 'desc': 'category number 1' }]}
```

I want to dump this in the following yaml format

```
---
items:
    - { id: 'it1', desc: 'item number 1', cat: 'cat1' }
categories:
    - { id: 'cat1', desc: 'category number 1' }
```

using  `yaml.dump(data)` outputs a yaml in the following format

```
categories:
- desc: category number 1
  id: cat1
items:
- cat: cat1
  desc: Item 1
  id: '1'
```

What do I need to add to change this? I have tried setting the `default_flow_style=False` with no difference.

Comment: Another solution is by using `ruamel.yaml` which is answered in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760452/1279157

Comment: yaml file just like json file, where you can get keys and values like resemblance of json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PyYAML, the option `default_flow_style` has three different values:

- `True`: everything is dumped in flow style
- `False`: everything is dumped in block style
- `None`: only the lowest level of dicts and lists is dumped in flow style

We changed the default from `None` to `False` in version 5.1 because many people complained about it. So you need `default_flow_style=None`.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I wanted. Thank you.