# Why should I close files in Python?

Tags: python

Usually when I open files I never call the `close()` method, and nothing bad happens.  But I've been told this is bad practice.  Why is that?

Comment: There are limits on the number of files you can have open - typically something like 512-4096. If you neglect to close your files you'll eventually get to the point where you cannot open new file descriptors (files, sockets, etc) You can easily get into this type of situation if you're crawling a directory of files and operating on each one. However, in most cases once a file descriptor object is out of scope it'll automatically be closed. However, depending on that behavior is sloppy.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For the most part, not closing files is a bad idea, for the following reasons:

1. It puts your program in the garbage collectors hands - though the file *in theory* will be auto closed, it may not be closed. Python 3 and Cpython generally do a pretty good job at garbage collecting, but not always, and other variants generally suck at it.
2. It can slow down your program. Too many things open, and thus more used space in the RAM, will impact performance.
3. For the most part, many changes to files in python do not go into effect until *after* the file is closed, so if your script edits, leaves open, and reads a file, it won't see the edits.
4. You could, theoretically, run in to limits of how many files you can have open.
5. As @sai stated below, Windows treats open files as locked, so legit things like AV scanners or other python scripts can't read the file.
6. It is sloppy programming (then again, I'm not exactly the best at remembering to close files myself!)

Answer (score 14):

Found some good answers:

> (1) It is a matter of good programming practice. If you don't close
>   them  yourself, Python will eventually close them for you. In some
>   versions of  Python, that might be the instant they are no longer
>   being used; in others, it  might not happen for a long time. Under
>   some circumstances, it might not  happen at all.
>
> (2) When writing to a file, the data may not be written to disk until
>   the file  is closed. When you say "output.write(...)", the data is
>   often cached in  memory and doesn't hit the hard drive until the file
>   is closed. The longer  you keep the file open, the greater the
>   chance that you will lose data.
>
> (3) Since your operating system has strict limits on how many file
>   handles can  be kept open at any one instant, it is best to get into
>   the habit of closing  them when they aren't needed and not wait for
>   "maid service" to clean up after  you.
>
> (4) Also, some operating systems (Windows, in particular) treat open
>   files as  locked and private. While you have a file open, no other
>   program can also open  it, even just to read the data. This spoils
>   backup programs, anti-virus  scanners, etc.

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Tutor-Why-do-you-have-to-close-files-td4341928.html
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 5):

Open files use resources and may be locked, preventing other programs from using them. Anyway, it is good practice to use `with` when reading files, as it takes care of closing the file for you.

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
   read_data = f.read()
```

Here's an example of something "bad" that might happen if you leave a file open.
Open a file for writing in your python interpreter, write a string to it, then open that file in a text editor. On my system, the file will be empty until I close the file handle.

Comment: Not good practice, per se. It doesn't really matter how you do it, although a lot of people like using with.

Answer (score 4):

The close() method of a file object flushes any unwritten information and closes the file object, after which no more writing can be done.

Python automatically closes a file when the reference object of a file is reassigned to another file. It is a good practice to use the close() method to close a file.[Here is the link about the close() method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to call `close()` when you're writing to a file.

Python automatically closes files most of the time, but sometimes it won't, so you want to call it manually just in case.

Comment: But you *should* close all resources you open.  The question is asking why that's the advice, not when you *have* to.  If you're in the practice of not closing read-only resources you'd do well to read the other answers here.

Comment: I do close read-only resources. I was trying to explain why nothing bad happens (usually) when you don't close files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with that recently:
I was writing some stuff to a file in a for-loop, but if I interrupt the script with ^C, a lot of data which should have actually been written to the file wasn't there. It looks like Python stops to writing there for no reason. I opened the file before the for loop. Then I changed the code so that Python opens and closes the file for ever single pass of the loop.

Basically, if you write stuff for your own and you don't have any issues - it's fine, if you write stuff for more people than just yourself - put a close() inside the code, because someone could randomly get an error message and you should try to prevent this.