# How to upload a bunch of files with Python requests module

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests

When I using the `requests` module to upload at least 400 files with one request, I got the `Too many open files` error on macOS system.

I have tried `ulimit -n 20000`.

Also checked:

- `sysctl kern.maxfiles` got `98304`
- `sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc` got `49152`

However, it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import requests


url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload'
file_path = '/Users/BonJu/Projects/downloads'
file_list = os.listdir(file_path)
files = []
for file in file_list:
    try:
        source = open(os.path.join(file_path, file), 'rb')
        files.append(('file', source))

    except Exception as e:
        print('File: %s, Error: %s' % (file, e.__str__()))
        continue

response = requests.post(url=url, data={'uploader': 'admin'}, files=files)
```

Terminal result:

```sh
File: test_252.docx, Error: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/Users/BonJu/Projects/downloads/test_252.docx'
File: test_253.docx, Error: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/Users/BonJu/Projects/downloads/test_253.docx'
File: test_254.docx, Error: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/Users/BonJu/Projects/downloads/test_254.docx'
...
File: test_418.docx, Error: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/Users/BonJu/Projects/downloads/test_418.docx'
```

Because it is an API server which links the sent log files to the issue I need all the files to be sent in one request, otherwise the manager will get several mails and won't be able to address the issues.

Is there any solution for this situation?

## Solution

I finally adjusted my API to save a temp file for storing the upload logs and pass a `status` parameter to control the final output.

my code:

```py
payload = {
    'status': 'finish',
    'uploader': 'admin'
}
response = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, files=files)
```

API:

```py
@api_view(['post'])
def upload(request, debug, api_version):
    status = request.POST.get('status')
    file_list = request.FILES.getlist('file')

    if status == 'finish':
        # open the temp file and insert the last logs then output
        
    else:
        # create/insert the logs and save to a temp file

    return Response({'status': status, 'files': file_list})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I close files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070854/why-should-i-close-files-in-python)

Comment: If you need to pass the file handles to `requests.post` and cannot close them before sending, you need to make multiple requests with fewer files.

Comment: @mkrieger1 OK~ I think it might be the best way for my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest make a single `tar` file from all of them.

or closing the files after reading their content (instead of leaving their file descriptor open until you post the request

Comment: I will try the `tar` way later.
For the closing files tip, I tried and got `read of close file` after all.
Thanks for your suggestion.