# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment in Jupyter

Tags: python

everyone!

I'm working on a Python assignment where I have to do the below:

1. Read the text file from your local drive with some text in it. (The text is at the bottom).
2. Now using a for loop go over the text line by line and each time you read a line you should revers it and store it in a StringBuilder. (We learned this in a class previously). You can not use any python reverse string methods rather you have to write the code yourself to reverse the string. Once you have successfully reversed the entire file; display the data back on the screen
3. Now use a for loop to go over the text you read from the file and make every letter capitalized. You can use any python upper methods for this part of the problem. Once the entire text is converted into upper text; display the data back on the screen. (Remember you can NOT read the entire text and use a method to convert the whole text with one method call rather I want to see you convert one letter at a time, thus use some loop to go over each character in the string at a time.

I can't seem to figure out why I keep running to that type error on Jupyter Notebook, so I'm hoping someone can help me out with this! ᵕ̈

[image]

I tried using different StringBuilder methods, but I was unsure how that worked with my loops.

Comment: Note what the second line makes `infile`. You can't reassign a string's characters. Use a list if you need that, then `join` the list to a string at the end. Also, post all code here as text, not images.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post all code, output, and error messages as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you do `infile[i] = capitalizedText`, you are reassigning  the i'th character in infile, which is not allowed.  This is because, in Python, strings are immutable.  I think you may be misunderstanding infile though.

When you do `infile = infile.read()` on line 2, what you're returned is the entire file as a string.  So, when you say `lines = infile[i]` on line 12, this is just a single character.  So, `capitalizedTxt` will only contain one capitalized character when you try to reassign it to `infile[i]`.

It seems like you might be trying to have capitalizedTxt be each line of the file, so it seems like you want `infile` to be a list of every line in your file instead.  There are two ways you could go about doing this.

1. On line 2, you can do `infile = infile.readlines()` or `infile = list(infile)`.  According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), either of these will give you a list where each element is a line in the file.
2. After line 2, you could do `infile = infile.split("\n")`.  This will split the string at each newline and give you the resulting strings in a list.  So, it does the same thing as the previous one.

However, if you don't want to make `infile` a list of the lines in the file, you could still do it using what you have right now, though you will need to create a new string to store the capitalized text in rather than modifying `infile`.  The following should work:

```py
capitalized_text = ""
for character in infile:
    capitalized_text += character.upper()
```

Now, I also wanted to mention a couple of tips about your code overall.

1. In Python, you generally try to avoid using indices when you don't need to.  You can shorten your code and make it much more readable by eliminating them in your code.  A typical rule of thumb is that you should never be writing `range(len(...))` in your for loops.  Even on line 11, where you need the index to try to modify `infile[i]`, it is better to use the [enumerate function](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) to iterate over each item and its index simultaneously.  For example, on lines 14 and 15, you could have written the following, which allows you to give `lines[c]` a more meaningful name and cleans up the code:

```py
    for char in lines:
        capitalizedTxt += char.upper()
```

2. Note that on line 2, you are reassigning `infile` to the result of `infile.read()`, meaning you no longer have a reference to the file.  This is bad, because you are supposed to close any file you open using the `.close()` method.  Rather, you should store the result of `infile.read()` in a different variable than `infile`, and then once you are finished with the file, you should call `infile.close()`.  Even better if you use the `with` keyword, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for) for how it works, it automatically opens and closes file for you.  And also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070854/why-should-i-close-files-in-python) for reasons why you should be closing your files.

Comment: @mgold925 thank you so much for the help! I made some changes to my code, but I'm still having one minor issue with my code. The first part works like it should by reversing the text, but its the second part that does not work. The second part is that the text should print BOTH reversed AND capitalized.