# How to receive Yaml content in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my application, there is an endpoint that sends me the raw contents of a Yaml file in response to an AJAX call. I want to display them as they are in UI. The console throws an obvious error, which is for invalid JSON. How would I do it?

Update:

[This is the snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/) used for reading the file and sending the response.

```
filename = __file__ # Select your file here.                                
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
return response
```

Is there a way I could form a dictionary there with the contents of the file and then send the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From server, use `jsonify` on the raw content, pack it and ship it over to client.

```
repacked_json = json.dumps(raw_yaml_data) 
json_obj = json.loads(repacked_json)
return jsonify(result = json_obj)
```

Comment: The server is Python-Django, and it uses Django Rest Framework, if that helps!

Comment: Okay, let me ask the backend guy to try it. Thanks!

Comment: Django Rest Framework also supports Content Negotiation. Try asking the service endpoint for `application/json` and you might find that you get it.

Comment: I'm editing my question and adding the Python code that is used for sending the file contents.

Comment: You can take a look at this link here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file)

Comment: We used `json.dumps` and read the file using `file.read()`. Sent it across as `application/json` and then used `<pre></pre>` to display it! Thanks all you guys!