# Writing a dictionary to a textile line by line

Tags: python

I have some code that creates a dictionary and pastes it into a text file. But it pastes the dictionary as one line. Below I have the code and the textfile it creates.

```
print('Writing to Optimal_System.txt in %s\n' %(os.getcwd()))    
f = open('Optimal_System.txt','w')
f.write(str(optimal_system))
f.close
```

Is there any way to make the textfile give each key-value pair it's own line like this?

```
{'Optimal Temperature (K)': 425
 'Optimal Pressure (kPa)': 100
 ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: As the duplicate target suggests, use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to do this.

Comment: Iterate over the key,value pairs of `yourdictionary.items()`; use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to construct a line (with a newline character) from each key/value; write the line to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using formatting string and assuming that `optimal_system` is your dictionary:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k in optimal_system.keys():
        f.write("{}: {}\n".format(k, optimal_system[k]))
```

**EDIT**

As pointed by @wwii, the code above can be also written as:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in optimal_system.items():
        f.write("{}: {}\n".format(k, v))
```

And the string can be formatted using [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), available since python 3.6, hence `f'{k}: {v}\n'` instead of `"{}: {}\n".format(k, v)`.

Comment: `for k,v in optimal_system.items(): ... .format(k,v)...`.  And for Python 3.6 the line can be made with an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) - `f'{k}: {v}\n`.

Comment: @wwii I will add this in the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Just curious though, should I type in "f.close()" outside the for loop just to make sure its closed?

Comment: @bbalzano with the construct `with open('filename', 'w') as f:` calling `f.close()` is not needed. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512990/does-python-gc-close-files-too) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`pprint` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) -- it also works for all other data structures.
To force every entry on a new line, set the `width` argument to something low. The `stream` argument lets you directly write to the file.

```
import pprint
mydata = {'Optimal Temperature (K)': 425,
          'Optimal Pressure (kPa)': 100,
          'other stuff': [1, 2, ...]}
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    pprint.pprint(mydata, stream=f, width=1)
```

will produce:

```
{'Optimal Pressure (kPa)': 100,
 'Optimal Temperature (K)': 425,
 'other stuff': [1,
                 2,
                 Ellipsis]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.dumps() to do this with the indent parameter. For example:

```
import json

dictionary_variable = {'employee_01': {'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Doe'},
                       'employee_02': {'fname': 'Jane', 'lname': 'Doe'}}

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dictionary_variable, indent=4))
```