# How to properly close the file opened by the class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-multiprocessing, ftplib

I have a class I use to track the progress of an ftp download (using `ftplib`).
I use `ftplib` with `multiprocessing` to download several files at once.
This is my first attempt at using a class in Python and I am doubtful whether I am closing a file I opened inside the class. The code snippets I think relevent are given below:

```
class track_transfer:
    def __init__(self, size, fname):
        self.file_name=fname
        self.size_in_bytes=size
        self.downloaded=0
        self.file=open(fname, 'wb')

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.file.close()
            self.file=None
        except:
            pass

    def update(self):
        self.downloaded=self.file.tell()
        if self.downloaded==self.size_in_bytes:
            self.file.close()
```

As you can see, I try to close the files at two places: one inside the finalizer another in a class method `update()`.
What I wanted to know is will my file be closed correctly when I use this class?
Or is there a better method to follow?

**UPDATE**
I think I may need to provide more information here.

The class *track_transfer* has another method named *progress(self, data)* defined as follows:

```
    def progress(self, data):
        self.file.write(data)
        self.update()
```

Instantiating the classAdded more information,

```
tracker=track_transfer(size=fsize, fname=fname)
```

and downloading the file,

```
ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" %(fname),
        callback=tracker.progress)
```

where ftp.retrbinary() is a method defined in the [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) library to retrieve a file as binary from an ftp server. This will call the *tracker* objetc's *progress* method whenever a block of data is received. This means that the method **progress()** will be called several times when downloading a file.

Comment: Python doesn't really have destructors. You must be thinking of C++.

Comment: There's no point in your `__del__` function. Python will close a file when the associated file object is garbage collected anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512990/does-python-gc-close-files-too

Comment: @quamrana I thought __del__ in python is similar to destructors in C++? What are __del__ called in python then?

Comment: The `__del__` method is called a finalizer.

Comment: @freakish Then there's no point in using file.close() explicitly anywhere in a script, is there?

Comment: More info on `__del__`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481488/what-is-the-del-method-how-to-call-it

Comment: @RogUE In a perfect world yes. I.e. in such a world, where you do not store unused references to unused file objects. Because if you have such references then obviously the object won't be garbage collected. Another reason to use explicit `.close()` is when you don't won't to depend on GC and want to have explicit control for some reason (not sure why you'd want that).

Comment: Your `update()` method seems to call `close()` correctly: You have identified the ideal time for close. When the file is closed, the file system should make the file available to other users.

Comment: @quamrana What would happen if I terminate the program when it is running?

Comment: @RogUE All open file descriptors are closed by OS upon process termination. That doesn't mean that everything will be written to disk. Synching is a different problem.

Comment: I don't know. If you terminate the program, Python itself is the real program and you've just stopped it doing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The `__del__` probably does not help: it will only be called when the `track_transfer` instance is garbage-collected, and it will presumably be the only thing that has a reference to the file - so the file would be garbage-collected anyway, and Python will close the file when that object is garbage-collected. (__del__ is for very special-purpose cases that you will probably not run into; Python is naturally a garbage-collected language, so we generally don't bother with anything like "destructors".)

The normal way to manage the lifetime of a file object is using a `with` block:

```
with open(path, mode) as f:
    # do file operations
# file will be closed when the block is exited, even if by an exception etc.
```

This works because a file is its own ["context manager"](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/). Storing the file as a class attribute doesn't mesh too well with this approach, because you want to open the file in one class method call and close it at some later point. But we can fix this by making our class be a context manager, and using its context management instead of the file's.

Comment: Actually, the data is written to the file in a separate method of the class, which will be called repeatedly. That method then call the *update()* method. So, I am not sure whether this would work.

Comment: @RogUE: So the `track_transfer` class does more than track the transfer? Maybe your design is the issue.

Comment: From my quick read of the `ftplib` docs, it seems that the download calls will all just block and wait for the whole download anyway - so you'd have to do some kind of threading thing to monitor the download, and there is no need to make repeated calls to get all the data.

Comment: From the source code doc 'callback: A single parameter callable to be called on each block of data read'. So the function progress will be called several times in a download which gives me an opportunity to update **downloaded** variable of the class.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the docs, I got it from the source code at [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ftplib.py)

Comment: So to make my class act as a context manager, I should make use of the methods discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit), right?

Comment: Right, or in the link I provided.