# Problem when adding multiple files from list

Tags: python

My problem is that I have so many torrent files that I need to attach. I have them all in a list.

```
torrent_list = ['file1.torrent', 'file2.torrent', etc.......]
```

Downloading torrents by file:

```
torrent_file = open('my-torrent-file.torrent', 'rb')
qb.download_from_file(torrent_file)
```

Downloading multiple torrents by using files:

I Am not able to get it work without writing it manually like it is shown in the example.
I want to load them all from the list. can someone help with this?

```
torrent_file_list = [open('1.torrent', 'rb'), open('2.torrent', 'rb')]
qb.download_from_file(torrent_file_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
torrent_list = ['file1.torrent', 'file2.torrent']
for myFile in torrent_list:
  with open(myFile,'rb') as torr:
    qb.download_from_file(torr)
```

Comment: so, this method worked but after some time it breaks. via this examplea it was able to load 116 torrent files to my torrent client then its broke.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension.

```
torrent_file_list = [open(filename, 'rb') for filename in torrent_list])
qb.download_from_file(torrent_file)
for f in torrent_file_list:
    close(f)
```

Comment: when it comes to the function `open` you must use it in a context manager, so the file close at the end. If you don't close the file then it could break it. And in this example you are not closing the file

Comment: I believe that the garbage collector will automatically close the files in this case.

Comment: You are right. I search for it and seems to be as you say. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512990/does-python-gc-close-files-too#:~:text=Taken%20from%20the%20docs%20(python%203.6)%3A&text=If%20you%20don%27t%20explicitly,clean-up%20at%20different%20times.) Sorry  and thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: You're right that it's generally preferable to open and close explicitly or use a context manager. But for this it was simpler to do it this way.

Comment: so it is still not working for me.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\torrents\src\torrenthooker.py", line 15, in <module>
    qb.download_from_file([open(torrent_list, 'rb') for filename in torrent_list])
  File "D:\torrents\src\torrenthooker.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    qb.download_from_file([open(torrent_list, 'rb') for filename in torrent_list])
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Then the documentation is wrong, because it says that it allows a list of open files.

Comment: This should work just like `torrent_file_list = [open('1.torrent', 'rb'), open('2.torrent', 'rb')]` that you showed in your question.

Comment: yes it works, but i have thousand of files in my list.

Comment: Why does the number of files in the list make a difference? Either it allows a list or it doesn't. If it works when you create the list by hand, it should also work when the list is created using a list comprehension.