# Does deleting a dictionary close the file descriptors inside the dict?

Tags: python, io, garbage-collection, file-descriptor

### Clarified

There are two questions indeed.  Updated to make this clearer.

I have:

```
t = {
    'fd': open("filename", 'r')
}
```

I understand that `del t['fd']` removes the key and closes the file.    Is that correct?

Does `del t` call `del` on contained objects (`fd` in this case)?

Comment: It will eventually, but that may not be until the script ends — so it's not a good idea to count on it.

Comment: Generally, it's better to close the file explicitly (either using `close` or a `with` statement). Deleting the variable (directly or as part of a dict) isn't really the right way to do it

Comment: Per the documentation: "Warning Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Related question: [Does Python GC close files too?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49512990/10669875)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two parts of your question have completely different answers.

- Deleting a variable to close file is not reliable; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, or it works but in a surprising way. Occasionally it may lose data. It will definitely fail to report file errors in a useful way.

  The correct ways to close a file are (a) using a `with` statement, or (b) using the `.close()` method.
- Deleting an object indeed deletes all contained objects, with a couple of caveats:

  - if (some of) those objects are also in another variable, they will continue to exist until that other variable is also deleted;
  - if those objects refer to each other, they may continue to exist for some time afterwards and get deleted later; and
  - for immutable objects (strings, integers), Python may decide to keep them around as an optimisation, but this mostly won't be visible to us and will in any case differ between versions.

Comment: NB: when you use `.close()` instead a context manager (i.e. `with`), you should do that using `try-finally` to make sure the file is actually closed, even when some exception occurred.

Comment: From all the answers I get that `del t['fd']` does not deterministically and immediately close the file, even if that is the last reference to the file object. However, this conclusion is always hinted at, never stated explicitly with a reference, only recommendations. This sounds strange to me. I suppose a file object has a destructor, and this destructor closes the file. Is that true? If true, calling `del` on the last reference to the file object should not close the file immediately and reliably? (should I make this into a different question?)

Comment: That's what it says in the python manual; "might" lose data. See the red box at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: There are a couple of circumstances where she fine might not be closed properly at all; especially if the handle ends up in a global variable or a reference cycle. The other thing is that if the file close has an error, there's no way to report it; nowhere to raise an exception.

Comment: The main situation where it doesn't matter is if the file is opened read-only and the script is short-lived; in that case, it doesn't matter at all whether or not it's closed. It's still a good habit to do it properly, though.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of what you want to do is nondeterministic. Depending on the implementation and internal functioning of Python (CPython, PyPi, ...), this can be work or not:

**Working example**:

```
t = {
    'fd': open('data.txt', 'r')
}

def hook_close_fd():
    print('del dictionary, close the file')

t['fd'].close = hook_close_fd

del t
```

Output:

```
del dictionary, close the file
```

In this case, the `close` function is called on delete

**Non working example**:

```
t = {
    'fd': open('data.txt', 'r')
}

def hook_close_fd():
    print('del dictionary, close the file')

t['fd'].close = hook_close_fd

3 / 0
```

Output of 1st run:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-2d81419599a9> in <module>
     10 t['fd'].close = hook_close_fd
     11 
---> 12 3 / 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Output of 2nd run:

```
del dictionary, close the file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-212-2d81419599a9> in <module>
     10 t['fd'].close = hook_close_fd
     11 
---> 12 3 / 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

As you can see, when an exception is raised, you can't be sure if your file descriptor will be closed properly (especially if you don't catch exception yourself).

Comment: Ok, I think your answer and mine complement each other, I didn't know that close was called directly when deleting the descriptor.

Comment: Per the documentation: "Warning

Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully."

Comment: There's no way to tell if it's being called because the script is ending, or when the dict is deleted.

Comment: @martineau, that is simply tested by adding a sleep after the delete. However, that still proofs nothing. It is clearly not guaranteed but implementation-defined.

Comment: Apparently PyPy does it differently, for one

Comment: There are also circumstances where the last reference lasts longer than you'd expect; eg if an exception is raised, it'll keep a reference to all local variables

Comment: In any case, it's documented to be unsafe; if it happens to work under some circumstances, that's an implementation detail or even just luck

Comment: One real problem is that if closing the file has an error, there's nowhere for the exception to be raised, much less handled. A lot of file errors can happen on close...

Comment: @JiříBaum. I tested with an exception and the behavior is different between two runs. Nice point.

Comment: I think that may not be random, just later than expected; if that's IPython / Jupyter, it's quite possible that the "del dictionary, close the file" in the second run actually belongs to the first run, triggered when the variable `t` and/or the "last unhandled exception" variable got new values (thereby deleting the values from the first run). You can test that by using a different message on each run. Not that it changes much - it's still not the desired, reliable behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

No. You must close the files you open (see note).

Or, but it may not fit your project, in a more safer way open it in a context manager.

```
with open("filename", 'r') as fd:
    ...
```

If you are opening simultaneously a unknown number of files, you may need to write you own context manager or more simply use `contextlib.ExitStack`

**Note:**
From :
*"3.10.0 Documentation /
The Python Tutorial /
7. Input and Output /
7.2. Reading and Writing Files
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files"*:
***Warning Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully.***

Answer (score 2):

Your question is less trivial than you think. But deep down it all comes down to understanding what a pointer is and how the garbage collector works.

Indeed, by doing `t['fd']`, you delete that entry in the dictionary. What you do is delete the pointer that points to that entry. If you have a dictionary as follows:

```
t = { 'a':3, 'b':4 }
```

Then when you do `del t` you delete the pointer to the dictionary `t`. As there is therefore no further reference to the dictionary keys, the garbage collector deletes these as well, thus freeing up all the dictionary memory.

However, as long as you have a file descriptor, you can delete it but it is not desirable to do so since the file descriptor (`fd`, pointer to a file and much more ) is the way the programmer interacts with a file, if the descriptor is deleted abruptly, the state of the file can get corrupted by being in an inconsistent state.

Therefore, it is a good idea to call the `close` function before you stop working with a file. This function takes care of all those things for you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, deleting the variable `t` closes the file ([using `psutil` to show open files per process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25069136/7216865)):

```
import psutil


def find_open_files():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == 'python3.9':
            print(proc.open_files())


filename = '/tmp/test.txt'
t = {'fd': open(filename, 'r')}
find_open_files()
del t
find_open_files()
```

Out:

```
[popenfile(path='/private/tmp/test.txt', fd=3)]
[]
```

Comment: As discussed in various other answers and comments, this is not reliable and may lose data in some circumstances

Comment: The time I answered, the question was about: `Does deleting an object delete all contained objects?` Not, if there are any side effects.

Comment: If that's the question, then "_yes, deleting the variable t closes the file_" is a strange answer, don't you think? (Since the question is not about closing a file.) Although this is a common problem when the question is based on an incorrect premise _and_ contains multiple questions in one...