# How to read a content of a file obtained from os.listdir?

Tags: python, file-not-found, python-os, listdir

I am trying to read a CSV file. I have two CSVs under two folders. I get the CSV file but when I try to read the content, it says that I dont have such file or directory.

```
import os
import csv

def scanCSVFile(folder, output_file_name):
    myfile = open(output_file_name, "a")
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'): #gives two csv files
            with open(file) as csvfile: 
                csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                next(csvreader)
                for line in csvreader:
                    print (line)

    myfile.close()


def openCSV(path):
    scanCSVFile("./src/goi","goi.yml")
    scanCSVFile("./src/kanji","kanji.yml")

openCSV('.')
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Peace\Documents\LMS>python csvToYaml.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "csvToYaml.py", line 26, in <module> openCSV('.') 
File "csvToYaml.py", line 24, in openCSV scanCSVFile("./src/goi","goi.yml") 
File "csvToYaml.py", line 14, in scanCSVFile with open(file) as csvfile:  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pro.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete break from code

```
import os,glob

folder_path = r'path'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.csv')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from csv file using pandas.Data will be stored in dataframes.
".yml" extension is obsolete now. Mostly ".yaml" is used. 
The below link shows how to read .yaml files.
[How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

`# loading libraries and reading the data from csv files.
import pandas as pd
market_df = pd.read_csv("./src/goi.csv")
print(market_df)`