# Convert Multiline String to Dict - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, string-parsing

I have a multiline string, and I want to convert into Dict. the multiline string seems like

```
text='''
     one:
        two:
            three
            four
        five:
            six
            seven
     '''
```

And i did,

```
result={}
step1=step2=step3=''
lines=text.split('\n')
```

the following code that I tried to convert that 'text' to Dict

```
for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'^(\w+):$',line,re.M):
        out=re.search(r'^(\w+):$',line,re.M)
        step1=out.group(1)
        result[step1]={}
    if re.search(r'^\s{4}(\w+):$',line,re.M):
        out=re.search(r'^\s{4}(\w+):$',line,re.M)
        step2=out.group(1)
        result[step1][step2]={}
    if re.search(r'^\s{8}(\w+)$',line,re.M):
        out=re.search(r'^\s{8}(\w+)$',line,re.M)
        item1=out.group(1)
        result[step1][step2]=[]
        result[step1][step2].append(item1)

print(result)
```

But when I ran this code I'm getting output like:

```
{'one': {'two': ['four'], 'five': ['seven']}}
```

And the Expected result should be:

```
{'one': {'two': ['three','four'], 'five': ['six','seven']}}
```

Can anyone help me with this ...

Comment: Python **2**.7 and `print(result)`?

Comment: @OcasoProtal it's a perfectly valid syntax, even if the tag is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result[step1][step2]=[]
result[step1][step2].append(item1)
```

To

```
if not result[step1][step2]:
    result[step1][step2]=[item1]
else:
    result[step1][step2].append(item1)
```

Also you can write your parse logic as follows:

```
for line in lines:
    out = re.search(r'^(\w+):$',line,re.M)
    if out:
        step1 = out.group(1)
        result[step1] = {}
        continue
    out = re.search(r'^\s{4}(\w+):$',line,re.M)
    if out:
        step2 = out.group(1)
        result[step1][step2] = []
        continue
    out = re.search(r'^\s{8}(\w+)$',line,re.M)
    if out:
        item = out.group(1)
        result[step1][step2].append(item)
```

Comment: got it... Thanks :)

Comment: @qwerty You are welcome. If this answer resolve your question, please just accept it. :)