# Using YAML file as data source in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django and django-rest-framework.

I have a YAML file that represents a database.
Every object has an id and data.

I want to be able to use the data as a resource in drf.
I don't need to create new objects and save them, I just need to read it.

Am I supposed to use fixtures for this? Or is there a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Link here but I'll post the answer for laziness. [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

The easiest and purest method without relying on C headers is PyYaml ([documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml

with open("example.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```