# Replace values from YAML in JSON file - Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, yaml

I want to replace the values from YAML file into a JSON file using Python 3.

I have many JSON files where I want to get the values from a master YAML file and replace only certain values like source server ip, email, hostname.

E.g. I have this YAML file (mast_conf.yaml):

```yaml
-  sourcesystem1:
    sourceServer: 1.2.3.500
    MailTo: gokul@gmail.com
-  sourcesystem2:
    sourceServer1: 2.2.3.500
    sourceServer2: 3.2.3.500
    MailTo: gokul@gmail.com
```

A JSON file (sourcesystem1.json):

```
{
    "source":"sourcesystem1",
    "frequency":"daily",
    "sourceServer":"1.2.1.2",
    "hostName":"1.2.1.3",
    "fileFormat":"csv",
    "delimiterType":"semicolon"
}
```

Another JSON file (sourcesystem2.json):

```
{
    "source":"sourcesystem2",
    "frequency":"daily",
    "sourceServer":"1.2.3.2",
    "hostName":"1.2.1.7",
    "fileFormat":"csv",
    "delimiterType":"commaseperated"
}
```

Below is my code I am trying out to parse the value from the json file

```
import json
import yaml


with open("master_conf.yaml", 'r') as f:
yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(f)


yaml_config = {
list(config.keys()[0]): list(config[config.keys()[0]])
for config in yaml_config
}


json_files = ( "sourcesystem1.json",
"sourcesystem2.json",
)


for json_file in json_files:
with open(json_file, "r") as f:
sourcesystem_conf = json.load(f)


sourcesystem = sourcesystem_conf["source"]


if sourcesystem in yaml_config:
for key, value in yaml_config[sourcesystem].items():
sourcesystem_conf[key] = value


with open(json_file, "w") as f:
json.dump(sourcesystem_conf, f, indent=2)
```

I am getting the below error by program

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

When I run indivudually I get this issue for yaml

>>> yaml_config = { ... config.keys()[0]: config[config.keys()[0]] ... for config in yaml_config ... } Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module> File "<stdin>", line 3, in <dictcomp> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable >>>
```

Is there easier method to achieve my end goal where I want to replace the values in the JSON file from the Yaml configuration file

This is needed to update 1000s of Json file in a automated way for updating it from a master Yaml file

Comment: What about using pyyaml library to load the file (https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and use the json library to build the output ones (https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/json.html) ?

Comment: Please describe what exactly your problem with this task is. We are keen to help you figure out errors in your code or explain things you don't understand, but you seem to be just asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use pyyaml, see [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1774043/7685195).

Then you can load you yaml file using it :

```py
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
>>> yaml_config
[{'sourcesystem1': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com', 'sourceServer': '1.2.3.500'}},
 {'sourcesystem2': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com',
   'sourceServer1': '2.2.3.500',
   'sourceServer2': '3.2.3.500'}}]
```

It will be easier to manipulate a dict with source systems as keys.

In python 2 `aDict.keys()` returns a list so the following will work :

```py
>>> yaml_config = {
    config.keys()[0]: config[config.keys()[0]]
    for config in yaml_config
}
>>> yaml_config
{'sourcesystem1': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com', 'sourceServer': '1.2.3.500'},
 'sourcesystem2': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com',
  'sourceServer1': '2.2.3.500',
  'sourceServer2': '3.2.3.500'}}
```

In python 3 `aDict.keys()` no longer returns a list so you can simply use a for loop :

```
yaml_config = {}
for config in yaml_config_raw:
    source = [key for key in config][0]
    yaml_config[source] = config[source]
```

Then you can just iterate over your json files to update them :

```py
import json
import yaml

with open("mast_conf.yaml", 'r') as f:
    yaml_config_raw = yaml.safe_load(f)


yaml_config = {}
for config in yaml_config_raw:
    source = [key for key in config][0]
    yaml_config[source] = config[source]

json_files = (
    "sourcesystem1.json",
    "sourcesystem2.json",
)

for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file, "r") as f:
        sourcesystem_conf = json.load(f)

    sourcesystem = sourcesystem_conf["source"]

    if sourcesystem in yaml_config:
        for key, value in yaml_config[sourcesystem].items():
            sourcesystem_conf[key] = value

    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        json.dump(sourcesystem_conf, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: thank you . I tried to run . I am getting this error

Comment: sorry it's json.load

Comment: import json
import yaml
import sys

with open("master_conf.yaml", 'r') as f:
    yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(f)

json_file=sys.argv[1]

for json_file in json_file:
 with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
    sourcesystem_conf = json.load(f)

    sourcesystem = sourcesystem_conf["source"]
    if sourcesystem in yaml_config:
        for key, value in yaml_config[sourcesystem].items():
            sourcesystem_conf[key] = value
            print ('export {}={}'.format(key, value))
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        json.dump(sourcesystem_conf, f, indent=2)

Comment: I am getting the error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 't'

Comment: the values are not getting replaced in the json file here. empty lines are printed. when I print the values

Comment: It's working for me... Did you use the last version ?

Comment: I am getting this error ,after updating your latest code - TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser8.py", line 9, in <module>
    for config in yaml_config
  File "parser8.py", line 9, in <dictcomp>
    for config in yaml_config

Comment: >>> yaml_config = {
...     config.keys()[0]: config[config.keys()[0]]
...     for config in yaml_config
... }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
>>>

Comment: it would be great if you can update the solution here

Comment: We are not using the same version of python. I updated my answer