# AWS Lambda get output queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to the aws serverless world and I have the following simple system:

- an input queue which invoke a lambda for each input it has
- the lambda do some work on that input and then push it into an output queue

My question is how can i get the output queue url/physical name?

I found 2 solutions so far:

1. pass it by env variable in the cloudformation `template.yml` file. The con is that I have to provide this env variable every time. And in complex system there are a lot such variables. Thats feels fishy to me.
2. use `boto3.resource('cloudformation').StackResource(stack name, resource name).physical_resource_id`. The con is that I hard coded the template structure in my code.

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store to store the queue name as an [AWS::SSM::Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) resource and retrieve it from the Lambda function. [Here’s an example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) using a secure string, but you can do the same with clear text parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a json file with lambda having all the constants.

Pros.

- Easy to read and low latency.
- Can hold large number of constants in a nested structure.

Comment: Can I include values from it in the template.yaml file? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python.

Comment: So your suggestion is editing the `template.yml` file and specify the constants in it. Then create a new template yml file and deploy it?

Comment: In the lambda code keep a yml or json file with constants like  queue url  and in the lambda code read that constants. Now you don't have to keep the url in template file anymore.