# How to join list from th yaml file in python

Tags: python, yaml

How to Join the list based on `YAML` file, i have below file which need to join by space delimitation.

```
$ cat File.yml
---
fruits:
 - orange
 - banana
 - apple
 - strawberry
 - berry
 - cherry
...
```

### What i tried:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> with open('File.yml') as f:
...   result = yaml.safe_load(f)
...   print(result)
...
{'fruits': ['orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'berry', 'cherry']}
```

Can we do something `{{ fruits[ item ] | join(' ') }}"` ?

### Desired:

```
"orange banana apple strawberry berry cherry"
```

I don't require `","` in the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

Comment: @sushanth, thats Doesn't Answer my question, i will add more explanation.

Comment: `' '.join(result['fruits'])`!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Comment: Thank you guys for all your suggestions, these are valuable for me.

Comment: @mkrieger1, truly useful comment 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
import yaml


with open('File.yml') as f:
    result = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(' '.join(result['fruits']))
```

Output:

```
orange banana apple strawberry berry cherry
```

Answer (score 1):

Just going on top of what you already have.

```py
>>> with open("File.yml") as f:
...   result = yaml.safe_load(f)
>>> " ".join(result["fruits"])
"orange banana apple strawberry berry cherry"
```

You can refer to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for a more in-depth description on the syntax of the `.join`. The gist of it is that we need

```
str.join(iterable)
```

In this case, we want to join by empty spaces, `" "`, and we want to iterate through the contents of `result["fruits"]`" to join the items into one string.

Comment: Thanks @Jake,  for adding the explanation, i got a lesson for the day.