# How can I add something to a list on YAML file? using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, yaml, discord.py, pyyaml

How can I add value to an existing list of YAML files using the discord.py command?

here's what I've tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def addwhitelist(ctx, id : int=None):
    with open("./config.yml", "r") as file:
      data = file.readlines()
    data[0][49] = f", {id}"

    with open("./config.yml", "w") as file:
      file.writelines(data)
      file.close()
```

and here's what's the list:

`Whitelist: [483686172221243402, 740936250608844890]`

**NOTE:** I want it to add more than once so whenever I want to add a new value to that list.

so how can I do that?

Comment: It seems like you aren’t doing anything with the i`d` variable. What's it for?

Comment: @WasiMaster oh, ill edit that, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

Comment: @enzo Nope.  I want to make a discord.py command that makes me can add new ID's to 'Whitelist' list in config.yml file.

Comment: So parse the YAML file using the link I've sent, save it to a variable, access the 'Whitelist' list on the parsed variable, add the ID to it and save it back to the YAML file.

Comment: @enzo okay.. but I want to it to be in discord.py command.

Comment: So just put the logic I've sent inside the `addwhitelist` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the pyyaml library:

```
import yaml
@bot.command()
async def addwhitelist(ctx, id):
    with open('./config.yml', 'r') as f:
        conf = yaml.safe_load(f)
        conf['Whitelist'].append(id)
    with open('./config.yml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(conf, f)
```

The usage of discord.py here is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have a YAML file where the first line looks like `Whitelist: [483686172221243402, 740936250608844890]`.

You want to be able to add new numbers to this list. So for example adding a new number `83298234892891392` inside the list, while keeping the other numbers there.

To do this, I would do:

```
def whitelist(id: int):
    with open("./config.yml", "r") as file:
        lines = tuple(file)

    lines[0].removeprefix('Whitelist: ')
    whitelist = eval(lines[0])
    whitelist.append(id)
    lines[0] = 'Whitelist: ' + str(whitelist)

    with open("./config.yml", "w") as file:
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line)
```