# How to add a mapping in yaml file using python

Tags: python, yaml, mapping

I have a below yml file samplelambda1.yml

```
Mappings:
  Environments:
    dev:
        DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    test:
        DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    staging:
        DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    production:
        DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
```

I have multiple files like samplelambda2,3,4....30

I need to add another mapping to all the yml file with help of python script, how can we do it? I tried string replace but its a complicated operation to open a file and replace multiple lines.

```
production-new:
    DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
```

Comment: The question appears to be "how do I properly handle yaml files in Python?" and the answer is that there isn't built-in standard library support and you would be better off with a third-party library rather than trying to write it yourself, because it is a standard format with a lot of established support (but hasn't yet made it into the standard library). Requests for such are off topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest you try [an internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+yaml). This [should have been your first step anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/).

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me thanks to [@kaushal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353128/kaushal28)

for multiple file I am iterating the code in a for loop

```
data={}

with open("test.yml") as ymlfile:
    data = yaml.load(ymlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    print(data)

data['Mappings']['Environments']['production-new'] = {'DefaultLambdaConcurrency': '10'}

print(data)

with open("test.yml",'w') as ymlfile:
    dumpdata = yaml.dump(data)
    ymlfile.write(dumpdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle yaml files in python with [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). To add to the existing yaml you could do something like:

```
import yaml

with open("file_append.yaml", "r") as fs:
        append_dict = yaml.load(fs, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

append_to = ["file_1.yaml"]

for file_name in append_to:
    with open(file_name, "r") as fs:
            target_dict = yaml.load(fs, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

    target_dict["Mappings"]["Environments"] = {**target_dict["Mappings"]["Environments"], **append_dict}

    with open(file_name, "w") as fs:
            yaml.dump(target_dict, fs)
```

Output:

```
Mappings:
  Environments:
    dev:
      DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    production:
      DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    production-new:
      DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    staging:
      DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
    test:
      DefaultLambdaConcurrency: '10'
```

Answer (score -1):

The question shows no effort (no offence but OP should try his approach and post wherever he's stuck) so here is just the hint.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    // read each YAML using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1774043/5353128
    // add your key value in the read YAML dict.
    // Use yaml.dump() to save the content back to file.
```

Comment: If a question doesn't meet standards, you should post a comment to that effect and vote to close it, rather than attempting an answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe in helping people rather than following "standards".

Comment: That's fine, but Stack Overflow exists to be searched by others later on. It is *not a discussion forum*.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a head start to work on something thank you @Kaushal28

Comment: But the challenge is that the yaml file is integrated with jinja yaml.j2 extention and yaml.load can read it any Idea how can we parse yaml integrated with jinja?