# ChartID in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

How to find chartID for specific chart in Apache Superset?

I am unable to find chartID. In this discussion, [Superset: How to find all dashboard using a specific chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660787/superset-how-to-find-all-dashboard-using-a-specific-chart)
they mentioned chartID=42. where that 42 is coming from???

Comment: 42 usually is a random number.

Comment: You can hit the API endpoint `/api/v1/chart` to get a list of your charts. There you will see the id of each chart. 42 was just an example id.

Answer (score 1):

- Select the specific chart you want and open it in new tab
- See the URL; at last, most parts are there in sliceid=1234.
- chart ID is 1234.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer is clear enough and is one way to get the sliceid, which is the chart id.

Another way is to find the chart in the charts list page and mouse over the link to the chart.  Your browser should then popup the URL with the sliceid as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on any specific Chart/ any visual
2. Inspect the element
3. Expand the `<div>`, you will the chart ID in there.