# Python: can I safely unpickle untrusted data?

Tags: python, security, pickle

The [pickle module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-python-object-serialization) says right at the beginning:

> **Warning**: 
>   The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or
>   maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an
>   untrusted or unauthenticated source.

However, further down under [restricting globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#restricting-globals) it seems to describe a way to make unpickling data safe using a whitelist of allowed objects.

Does this mean that I can safely unpickle untrusted data if I use a `RestrictedUnpickler` that allows only some "elementary" types, or are there additional security issues that are not addressed by this method? If there are, is there another way to make unpickling safe (obviously at the cost of not being able to unpickle every stream)?

With "elementary types" I mean precisely the following:

- `bool`
- `str`, `bytes`, `bytearray`
- `int`, `float`, `complex`
- `tuple`, `list`, `dict`, `set` and `frozenset`

Comment: Is it important for your task to achieve something that `json` doesn't, e.g. forbidding the serialisation of `bool` types?

Comment: @Brian yes, the data already exists. Switching the format in the future is an option, but I'd still need to unpickle the data frist to do the conversion.

Comment: Oh... [bummer](http://dilbert.com/2014-08-12/) :(

Answer (score 22):

In this answer we're going to explore what exactly the pickle protocol allows an attacker to do. This means we're only going to rely on documented features of the protocol, not implementation details (with a few exceptions). In other words, we'll assume that the source code of the `pickle` module is correct and bug-free and allows us to do exactly what the documentation says and nothing more.

#### What does the pickle protocol allow an attacker to do?

Pickle [allows classes to customize how their instances are pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances). During the unpickling process, we can:

- Call (almost) any class's [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) method (as long as we manage to unpickle an instance of that class).
- Invoke arbitrary callables with arbitrary arguments, thanks to the [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) method (as long as we can gain access to the callable somehow).
- Invoke (almost) any unpickled object's `append`, `extend` and `__setitem__` methods, once again thanks to [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__).
- Access any attribute that [`Unpickler.find_class`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler.find_class) allows us to.
- Freely create instances of the following types: `str`, `bytes`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `int`, `float`, `bool`. This is not documented, but these types are built into the protocol itself and don't go through `Unpickler.find_class`.

The most useful (from an attacker's perspective) feature here is the ability to invoke callables. If they can access `exec` or `eval`, they can make us execute arbitrary code. If they can access `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` they can run arbitrary shell commands. Of course, we can deny them access to these with `Unpickler.find_class`. But how exactly should we implement our `find_class` method? Which functions and classes are safe, and which are dangerous?

#### An attacker's toolbox

Here I'll try to explain some methods an attacker can use to do evil things. Giving an attacker access to any of these functions/classes means you're in danger.

- **Arbitrary code execution during unpickling:**

  - [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) and [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (duh)
  - [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen), [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and all other `subprocess` functions
  - [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType), which allows to create a function from a code object (can be created with [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) or [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType))
  - [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints). Yes, you read that right. How, you ask? Well,  `typing.get_type_hints` evaluates forward references. So all you need is an object with `__annotations__` like `{'x': 'os.system("rm -rf /")'}` and `get_type_hints` will run the code for you.
  - [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). I see you shaking your head in disbelief, but it's true. Single-dispatch functions have a `register` method, which internally calls `typing.get_type_hints`.
  - ... and probably a few more
- **Accessing things without going through `Unpickler.find_class`**:

  Just because our `find_class` method prevents an attacker from accessing something *directly* doesn't mean there's no *indirect* way of accessing that thing.

  - **Attribute access:** Everything is an object in python, and objects have lots of attributes. For example, an object's class can accessed as `obj.__class__`, a class's parents can be accessed as `cls.__bases__`, etc.

    - [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)
    - [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)
    - [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)
    - [`Tools.scripts.find_recursionlimit.RecursiveBlowup5.__getattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Tools/scripts/find_recursionlimit.py#L56)
    - ... and many more
  - **Indexing:** Lots of things are stored in lists, tuples and dicts - being able to index data structures opens many doors for an attacker.

    - [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
    - `list.__getitem__`, `dict.__getitem__`, etc
    - ... and almost certainly some more

  See Ned Batchelder's [Eval is really dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) to find out how an attacker can use these to gain access to pretty much everything.
- **Code execution *after* unpickling:**

  An attacker doesn't necessarily have to do something dangerous *during* the unpickling process - they can also try to return a dangerous object and let *you* call a dangerous function on accident. Maybe you call `typing.get_type_hints` on the unpickled object, or maybe you expect to unpickle a `CuteBunny` but instead unpickle a `FerociousDragon` and get your hand bitten off when you try to `.pet()` it. Always make sure the unpickled object is of the type you expect, its attributes are of the types you expect, and it doesn't have any attributes you don't expect it to have.

At this point, it should be obvious that there aren't many modules/classes/functions you can trust. When you implement your `find_class` method, never *ever* write a blacklist - always write a whitelist, and only include things you're sure can't be abused.

#### So what's the answer to the question?

If you *really* only allow access to `bool`, `str`, `bytes`, `bytearray`, `int`, `float`, `complex`, `tuple`, `list`, `dict`, `set` and `frozenset` then you're *most likely* safe. But let's be honest - you should probably use JSON instead.

In general, I think most **classes** are safe - with exceptions like `subprocess.Popen`, of course. The worst thing an attacker can do is call the class - which generally shouldn't do anything more dangerous than return an instance of that class.

What you really need to be careful about is allowing access to **functions** (and other non-class callables), and how you handle the unpickled object.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go so far as saying that there is no safe way to use pickle to handle untrusted data.

Even with restricted globals, the dynamic nature of Python is such that a determined hacker still has a chance of finding a way back to the `__builtins__` mapping and from there to the Crown Jewels.

See [Ned Batchelder's blog posts on circumventing restrictions on `eval()`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/finding_python_3_builtins.html) that apply in equal measure to `pickle`.

Remember that `pickle` is still a stack language and you cannot foresee all possible objects produced from allowing arbitrary calls even to a limited set of globals. The pickle documentation also doesn't mention the `EXT*` opcodes that allow calling `copyreg`-installed extensions; you'll have to account for anything installed in that registry too here. All it takes is one vector allowing a object call to be turned into a `getattr` equivalent for your defences to crumble.

At *the very least* use a cryptographic signature to your data so you can validate the integrity. You'll limit the risks, but if an attacker ever managed to steal your signing secrets (keys) then they could again slip you a hacked pickle.

I would instead use an an existing innocuous format like JSON and add type annotations; e.g. store data in dictionaries with a type key and convert when loading the data.

Comment: In order to get from some (whitelisted) object to `__builtins__` using Ned's procedure, you need some way to retrieve object attributes (e.g. `getattr(obj, '__class__')` or `obj.__class__`). I don't think this is possible with the pickle protocol. You can retrieve globals ('`GLOBAL` opcode), call/instantiate them with arbitrary arguments (`REDUCE`, `INST`, `OBJ`, `NEWOBJ`, `NEWOBJ_EX`) and *set* their attributes (`BUILD`), but you cannot retrieve attributes. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've never seen my blog post connected to pickle before, but would like to know if it could be.  Pickle uses a stack-based execution machine, but it is not Python bytecode, so the possibilities are different.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: sure, but that doesn't mean I'd trust pickle even with a limited set of globals. All it it takes is one seemingly innocuous `__new__` method returning an attribute instead of a new instance when passed certain arguments. **I just would not trust near-arbitrary calling power**.

Comment: @Nikratio: I am not currently aware of an attack vector *but I cannot discount one either*. That should scare anyone; between the `copyreg` extensions that might be installed on an arbitrary system plus the ability to call `__new__` (which may or may not return an actual instance) the *possibility* still exists for an attacker to find a callable that produces a `getattr()` equivalent. Perhaps not now but in a future Python version. That's a *huge* risk in my eyes.

Comment: About `copyreg` extensions: First of all there's no such thing as "calling" copyreg extensions. An extension is simply an integer number that represents a `(module_name, qualname)` pair. Instead of dumping a 2-tuple to the output stream, pickle dumps the corresponding integer. That's all it is - a simple form of compression. They represent no danger at all. Every `(module_name, qualname)` pair is sent through `Unpickler.get_class`. See also [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copyreg.py#L150) in the `copyreg` source code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: The `module.name` reference is to a *callable object*, and all the same caveats apply as for other callables. It is not the registry contents itself that is dangerous, it is the fact that `EXT*` opcodes let you load callable objects to further exploit in the stack language.

Answer (score 2):

This idea has been discussed also on the mailing list [python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-ideas/) when addressing the problem of adding a safe `pickle` alternative in the standard library. For example [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-ideas/2013-February/019539.html):

> To make it safer I would have a restricted unpickler as the default (for load/loads) and force people to override it if they want to loosen restrictions. To be really explicit, I would make load/loads only work with built-in types.

And also [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-ideas/2013-February/019524.html):

> I've always wanted a version of pickle.loads() that takes a list of classes that are allowed to be instantiated.
>
> > Is the following enough for you: http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html#restricting-globals ?
> >
> > > Indeed, it is. Thanks for pointing it out! I've never gotten past the module interface part of the docs. Maybe the warning at the top of the page could also mention that there are ways to mitigate the safety concerns, and point to #restricting-globals?
> > >
> > > > Yes, that would be a good idea :-)

So I don't know why the documentation has not been changed but according to me, using a `RestrictedUnpickler` to restrict the types that can be unpickled is a safe solution. Of course there could exist bugs in the library that compromise the system, but there could be a bug also in OpenSSL that show random memory data to everyone who asks.

Comment: I like the OpenSSL reference

Comment: Also, many objects offer *indirect* access to globals, allowing an attacker to **still** get to load arbitrary objects. Restricting access to globals is **not enough**. I'd still recommend against using pickle when dealing with untrusted data.

Comment: See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/finding_python_3_builtins.html and related blog posts about circumventing `eval()` restrictions; those apply to unpickling just as much.