# get scaler transformation parameters from a different script

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created and saved a neural network on a script called "training_net.py".
As recommended in the sklearn website (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#tips-on-practical-use) I scaled the training set and used the same scaler for the test set.

Now I have a script, called "prediction.py", that takes as input a vector of parameters and the neural network created in "training_net.py" and gives a classification as output.

My doubt is about the scaling of my input in "prediction.py". I guess I should scale the input with the same transformation I used in "training_net.py", but I don't understand how to get the transformation parameters from the scaler used.

When I do scaler.get_params() I just get the following information:
*{'copy': True, 'with_mean': True, 'with_std': True}*

Here is a small code extract to show better what I mean.

*training_net.py*

```
#scale training and test data
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(training_data)

training_data = scaler.transform(training_data)
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)

clf.fit(training_data, training_label)
nn_name = "NN.pkl"
joblib.dump(clf, nn_name)

clf = joblib.load(nn_name)
print clf.score(test_data, test_label)
```

*prediction.py*

```
model_name = "NN.pkl"
clf = joblib.load(model_name)

#need to scale input_parameters before predicting!
#?

print clf.predict(input_parameters)
```

Comment: Why not pickle the StandardScaler too?

Comment: Also, what you need are the attributes, not parameters. See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) for available attributes which will be learnt from the data.

Comment: That was my problem, how to pickle it. Anyway, since I didn't know what pickle meant, I made a search with the keywords 'pickle standardscaler' and found the answer in Stackoverflow itself. Thank you! And you are right, I need attributes, not parameters, thanks for the clarification.
Here the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944783/how-to-store-scaling-parameters-for-later-use

Comment: In your code, you are already pickling the `clf` object using `joblib.dump`. Use the same technique to save the CountVectorizer.

Comment: Actually that answer is exactly what you said. Printing the available attributes. Could you write your comment as answer? Then I can confirm it and close the question.

Comment: ah! True. I didn't know I could use it for anything. Thanks

Comment: Glad could help. And its even [recommended by the scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) to use joblib instead of simple pickle to save scikit-learn objects.

Answer (score 0):

As Vivek Kumar answered in the comment, it is enough to pickle the Standard scaler.

```
joblib.dump(scaler, "scaler.pkl")
```

Here you can also find a similar question (and answer) I couldn't find in my first search:
[How to store scaling parameters for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944783/how-to-store-scaling-parameters-for-later-use)