# redis-py : What's the difference between StrictRedis() and Redis()?

Tags: python, redis

I want to use *redis-py* for caching some data, but I can't find a suitable explanation of the difference between `redis.StrictRedis()` and `redis.Redis()`. Are they equivalent?

In addition, I can't find any clear documentation about `redis.StrictRedis()`'s arguments in [Redis Python Docs](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest).
Any idea?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

EDIT: They are now equivalent:

> redis-py 3.0 drops support for the legacy "Redis" client class.
> "StrictRedis" has been renamed to "Redis" and an alias named
> "StrictRedis" is provided so that users previously using "StrictRedis"
> can continue to run unchanged.

Original answer:
[This seems pretty clear](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py):

```
 redis-py exposes two client classes that implement these commands
 The StrictRedis class attempts to adhere to the official command syntax.
```

and

```
In addition to the changes above, the Redis class, a subclass of StrictRedis,
overrides several other commands to provide backwards compatibility with older
versions of redis-py
```

Do you need backwards compatibility? Use `Redis`. Don't care? Use `StrictRedis`.

---

2017-03-31

Here are the specifics of the backwards compatibility, from the github.com link cited:

> In addition to the changes above, the Redis class, a subclass of StrictRedis, overrides several other commands to provide backwards compatibility with older versions of redis-py:
>
> LREM: Order of 'num' and 'value' arguments reversed such that 'num' can provide a default value of zero.
>
> ZADD: Redis specifies the 'score' argument before 'value'. These were swapped accidentally when being implemented and not discovered until after people were already using it. The Redis class expects *args in the form of: name1, score1, name2, score2, ...
>
> SETEX: Order of 'time' and 'value' arguments reversed.

---

Answer (score 74):

It's an old question but for anyone who reaches this question after google search:

from redis-py readme ([link](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)):

> redis-py 3.0 drops support for the legacy "Redis" client class.
>   "StrictRedis" has been renamed to "Redis" and an alias named
>   "StrictRedis" is provided so that users previously using "StrictRedis"
>   can continue to run unchanged.

Here is the line from redis-py code which defines `StrictRedis` ([link](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/d811ae71dbdbeeb4fc0ee73a96b7fbdb1aec8522/redis/client.py#L2996)):

```
StrictRedis = Redis
```